# Чтение excel файла

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, oledb

Привет всем. Вот пример нашел в инете. Кто знает, как прочитать только первый столбец excel файла? Т.е. мне надо отдельно прочитать все столбцы excel файла и занести их в массивы. Типа аналог с текстовым файлом (`*.txt`), вот код с `.txt`.

```
string section = sr.ReadLine();
if (section.ToLower() == "firstcolumn")
{
    string value = sr.ReadLine();
    qnnr = value.Split(' ');
}
```

Внизу чтение с Excel файла.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Имя файла
    string filename = @"C:\data.xls";

    // Строка подключения
    string ConnectionString = String.Format(
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No\";Data Source={0}", filename);

    // Открываем соединение
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("EXCEL");
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    cn.Open();

    // Получаем списко листов в файле
    DataTable schemaTable =
        cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
                new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    // Показать список листов в файле
    //for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    //{
    //    // Имена листов
    //    Console.WriteLine(schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);

    //    // Дата модификации
    //    Console.WriteLine(schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[7]);
    //}

    // Береме название первого листа
    string sheet1 = (string)schemaTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[2];
    // Выбираем все данные с листа
    string select = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheet1);
    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, cn);
    ad.Fill(ds);
    DataTable tb = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: Нужно 4 столбца отдельно прочитать

Comment: Вопрос закрыт!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [c# Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / Сsv файлы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас после всех манипуляций в DataTable.Columns будет описание столбцов. Если нужны ТОЛЬКО столбцы, то можно сделать SELECT TOP 0 * FROM sheet1. Если же данные на данном этапе вообще не нужны, то я бы сделал так:

```
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    cn.Open();

    // Получаем списко листов в файле
    DataTable schemaTable =
        cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
                new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    // Береме название первого листа
    string sheet1 = (string)schemaTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[2];
    // Выбираем все данные с листа
    string select = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheet1);

    OleDbCommand oleDB = new OleDbCommand(select, cn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = oleDB.ExecuteReader();
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        string name = reader.GetName(i); // Имя столбца
        Type type = reader.GetFieldType(i); // Тип столбца
    }
```

А вообще, я думаю, есть более "гуманные" способы через схемы.

**UPDATE**

Сразу не обратил внимание на строку подключения. Для указания того откуда что считать заголовками столбцов ипользуется параметр **HDR** строки подключения. Установите его в **TRUE** и получите в качестве имен столбцов то, что записано в первой строке. Подробнее про строки подключения можно посмотреть [тут](http://connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: если написать SELECT TOP 2 * from sheet1 -> получает первые две строки. А при TOP 0 ничего

Comment: И в tb.Columns ничего?

Comment: типа вот так, как второй пример там http://www.site-do.ru/db/sql4.php

Comment: в tb.columns находятся F1, F2, F3, F4.

Comment: Ну тогда читайте SELECT TOP 1 и читайте первую строку. Там должны быть имена столбцов

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: нашел другое решение, спасибо!)