# Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы

Tags: c#, excel, csv

Сколько я ни искал, всё как-то уж больно сложно и избыточно функционально...

А я хотел максимальной простоты — работать с таблицей как с двумерным массивом строк.

Ответ к которому я пришел -  внизу :)

---

Полная поддержка CSV должна в себя включать:

1. возможность изменять делимитер
2. считывание ячеек между делимитерами
3. считывание строк
4. если знак делимитера есть в ячейке, ячейка должна братся в кавычки и нормально обрабатыватся самым ридером
5. если знак перехода на следующую строку есть в ячейке, ячейка должна братся в кавычки и нормально обрабатыватся самим ридером.
6. если ячейка выделена кавычками, а внутри есть кавычки, то они так же должны обрабатыватся без ошибок.

Comment: хорошо работает только при количестве колонок не более 26

Comment: ...если под работой с Excel понимаете простое считывание/сохранение данных это одно, если построение диаграмм - совсем другое

Comment: @КонстантинПросекин не проверял, не нужно было так много колонок как-то. Если не забуду, через пару недель проверю и исправлю. Сейчас нету возможности :)

Comment: @Ev_Hyper большинству людей под самые частые задачи достаточно считывания/сохранения данных. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## EXCEL:

Здесь я написал очень простую библиотеку на основе ClosedXML для того, чтобы не задумываясь иметь возможность работать с таблицами MS Excel как с двумерным массивом: что может быть легче в использовании?

Пример конечного кода для работы с моим классом:

```
Excel xl = new Excel(); //создаем инстанс

xl.FileOpen("c:\\file1.xlsx"); //открываем файл

var row1Cell6Value = xl.Rows[0][5]; //вытягиваем значение из 1 строки 6й ячейки

xl.AddRow("asdf","asdffffff","5"); //добавляем еще одну строку с 3мя ячейками после последней существующей строки

xl.FileSave("c:\\file2.xlsx"); //сохраняем файл
```

Фактически, это и есть все методы — аскетский минимализм :)

Если нужно написать формулу, можно использовать следующий код:

```
var widthAdress = Excel.GetExcelPos(0, 1);
var heightAdress = Excel.GetExcelPos(0, 2);

xl.Rows[0][0] = String.Format("={0}*{1}", widthAdress , heightAdress);
```

## CSV:

И абсолютно с тем же подходом аскетизма есть не менее простая либа для работы с CSV файлами как с двумерным массивом данных.

> Не будет работать, например, на Unity. Это из-за того, что пришось
> использовать библиотеку VB. Но в десктопных приложениях все ок.

```
Csv csv = new Csv(); //создаем инстанс читалки

csv.FileOpen("c:\\file1.csv"); //открываем файл

var row1Cell6Value = csv.Rows[0][5]; //читаем 6ю ячейку 1й строки

csv.AddRow("asdf","asdffffff","5"); // добавляем строку из 3х ячеек

csv.FileSave("c:\\file2.csv"); // сохраняем файл
```

Актуальный код обоих классов вы найдете здесь:
https://github.com/ukushu/DataExporter

---

## Почему мой код написан именно так, а не иначе (Excel)

Этот блок будет полезен тем, кому будет мало моей либы, и кто хочет больше возможностей в работе с Microsoft Excel.

Сначала я пытался работать с Excel-файлами при помощи **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**, который по факту:

- Медленный *(я сейвил таблицу всего лишь в 11 250 ячеек на протяжении 22 секунд!!!)*. (ни в коем случае не используйте эту библиотеку для веб-сайтов или приложений, где на сервере генерируются файлы Office-форматов: у вас кончится оперативная память довольно быстро и сайт или приложение упадёт).
- У него много утечек памяти если с ним неправильно работать ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464115/186752 )
- Требует наличия MS Office определённой версии. На каждую машину, где будет работать ваше приложение.
- Неудобный в использовании.
- Имеет множество подводных камней из-за которых лишние Excel'евские сервисы будут оставаться запущенными...

Считаю очень неудачным решением через него взаимодействовать.

---

Потом я пытался работать через OleDB. Этот путь привел меня в никуда просто по той причине, что там невозможно работать с формулами. Считать формулу ты не можешь — только записать. В целом этот путь явно лучше, быстрее и приятнее, но отсутствие возможности править формулы меня очень огорчало.

---

И так я пришел к OpenXML. Как следствие — тоже относительно печальный опыт. Работать с ним просто-напросто неудобно. Не знаю, чем авторы думали.

---

И я пришел к конечному решению — обертки вокруг OpenXML - ClosedXML. Это решение уже позволило написать:

- Удобный и легко читаемый код либы.
- При этом достаточно быстрый код. (сейв файла на 20 000 ячеек обходится в 00:00:00.6787608, что быстрее более чем в 57 раз чем путь Interop).
- А также не требует установленного MS Excel. :)

Важные минуса:

- нужно уточнить что работает только с ".xlsx" файлами! **Но не с ".xls"!**
- Решение для работы с Excel требует подтягивание целых 2х библиотек (OpenXML, ClosedXML)

Comment: Аналогичные поиски привели к рефлексии [в реализации](https://github.com/ClnViewer/Dictionary-CSV-Extensions) :)

Comment: Тоже полезно, спасибо за дополнение)

Comment: Тоже перепробовал кучу разных способов работы с Excel и самое приятное - библиотека EPPlus. Единственный минус - совсем недавно она стала платной, но старые версии до сих пор можно использовать свободно :)