# C# Не вставляются данные в Excel файл при запуске oledbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не получается самостоятельно решить (или найти решение в интернете).

Задача: выгрузить данные из Oracle таблицы в Excel.
Для решения проблемы написал код, который успешно выгружал данные из Oracle процедуры, возвращающей курсор.

Но при попытке увеличить возвращаемый курсором объем данных (порядка 20 колонок и 90 000 строк), данные перестали выгружаться. Пробовал выгружать по 10 000 строк и сохранять данные, но после приблизительно 30 000 данные не грузятся.

При этом, процесс не останавливается, счетчик внутри цикла бежит, и `ExecuteNonQuery()` регулярно возвращает 10 000 вставленных строк, но при открытии Excel файла, в нем оказывается только, как правило, порядка 30 000 строк.

В текстовый файл в блоке `catch` не заносятся ошибки. Может быть, подскажете, как можно попытаться отловить ошибки?

Cтроки соединения не привожу, они заданы корректно, так как скрипт отрабатывает на небольших объемах данных.

Возможно, кто-либо сталкивался с такой проблемой? У меня найти похожие статьи не получилось. Буду рад любой помощи!

```
public static void Main()
{
    string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();

        string qwe_constr = "connection string";
        OracleConnection myADONETConnection = new OracleConnection(qwe_constr);

        string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + "E:\\qaz\\15.07.2016\\qwe" +
                            ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

        File.Delete("E:\\qaz\\15.07.2016\\qwe.xlsx");

        //fill datatable with data for insert
        myADONETConnection.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd_proc = new OracleCommand();
        cmd_proc.Connection = myADONETConnection;
        cmd_proc.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd_proc.CommandText = "procedure_name";
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("p_show_del", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 0;
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("p_type", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 3).Value = "INV";
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("p_errno", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 157;
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("outcur", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        DataTable dt_with_data = new DataTable();
        dt_with_data.Load(cmd_proc.ExecuteReader());
        myADONETConnection.Close();

        //string with column headers
        string TableColumns = "";
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt_with_data.Columns)
        {
            TableColumns += column + "],[";
        }

        // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
        TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
        TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);

        //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
        Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
        Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table [sheet1] (" + TableColumns + ")";
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Excel_OLE_Con.Close();

        //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
        //string with command
        Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
        String sqlCommandInsert = "";
        String sqlCommandValue = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dt_with_data.Columns)
        {
            sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
        }

        sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
        sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
        sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into [sheet1] (" + sqlCommandValue + ") VALUES(";

        int columnCount = dt_with_data.Columns.Count;

        int i_qaz = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt_with_data.Rows)
        {
            i_qaz++;
            Console.WriteLine(i_qaz.ToString());
            string columnvalues = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                int index = dt_with_data.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                columnvalues += "'" + dt_with_data.Rows[index].ItemArray[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "',";
            }
            columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
            var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // Create Log File for Errors
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("E:\\qaz\\15.07.2016\\qwe_" + datetime + ".log"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39410996/cant-export-large-data-from-oracle-to-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Откройте ваш excel файл zip-ом, разпакуйте, Выгрузите данные в xml 2-штуки, одна sheet1.xml, вторая sharedStrings.xml (словарь). Сгенерируйте xml - запакуйте zip и отдавайте как xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

А попробуй использовать либу из даной темы:
[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134)

Проверял даный код на очень больших файлах: 16 х 64000 ячеек. Проблем замечено не было.