# Как извлечь данные из Excel в datagridview по двух условиям?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2015

**Имеется:**

База данных в `Excel`, содержащая *10 000 штук строк* и *10 штук столбцов*.

---

**Вопрос:**

> 1. Каким способом оптимально извлечь из Ексель данные по двум условиям в три разные datagridview?
> 2. Извлекаются следующие столбцы таблицы:
>
>    - ID;
>    - наименование;
>    - кол;
> 3. Таблица извлекается с заголовками столбцов (по возможности);

---

**Сценарий:**

> 1. Вносим ID задания.
> 2. Вносим путь к файлу.
> 3. Нажимаем кнопку "ИЗВЛЕЧЬ".
> 4. Данные извлекаются в зависимости от "ID" и "порядковый номер" в соответствующую datagridview.

---

**Код:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\";", textBox1.Text));

    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Лист1$]", connection);
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("1", "1");
    dataGridView2.Columns.Add("1", "1");
    dataGridView3.Columns.Add("1", "1");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader[0].ToString() == textBox2.Text)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]) > 10 && Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]) < 14) dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader[1].ToString());
            if (Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]) > 20 && Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]) < 24) dataGridView2.Rows.Add(reader[1].ToString());
            if (Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]) > 30 && Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]) < 34) dataGridView3.Rows.Add(reader[1].ToString());
        }
    }
    connection.Dispose();
}

private void textBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel 2003(*.xls)|*.xls|Excel 2007(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```

---

**Приложение:**

1. Проект "[http://файлообменник.рф/ltaxcgqovbvb.html](http://%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA.%D1%80%D1%84/ltaxcgqovbvb.html)".
2. Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Берешь код отсюда:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

А дальше проверяешь порядковый номер во второй строке... вроде

```
for (int i< excel.Rows.Cuunt; i++)
{
    var number = Int32.Parce(excel.Rows[i][1]);
    if (number>10 && number<20)
    {
    закидаешь код в нужный датагрид
    }
}
```