# Выгрузка Excel из процессов - C#

Tags: c#, excel, процесс

Доброго времени суток всем! Есть код, который из Excel передает все данные на форму в dataGridView1. Естественно после работы с Эксель нужно выгрузить все его барахло для того чтобы он не висел в процессах. Весь код находился в button_Click. Выгрузка работала и процесс завершался корректно сразу после выполнения. Понадобилось перенести весь код в функцию и вызывать ее по клику. Перенес и процесс остается висеть в процессоре задач. Погуглил и ничего не нашел Что я делаю не так?
Код.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test();

    }
    public void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
    public void test()
    {
        dsTest dSet = new dsTest();
        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet;
        Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook;
        Excel.Range ExcelRange;

        var workbooks = ExcelApp.Workbooks;
        ExcelWorkBook = workbooks.Open(@"D:\\Эксель.xlsm", 0, false);
        ExcelWorkSheet = ExcelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
        ExcelRange = ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ExcelRange.Rows.Count - 2; Rnum++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dSet.DataTable1.NewRow();
            for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ExcelRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
            {
                if ((ExcelRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                {
                    dr[Cnum - 1] =
        (ExcelRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                }
            }
            dSet.DataTable1.Rows.Add(dr);
            dSet.DataTable1.AcceptChanges();
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dSet.DataTable1;
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        ExcelWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        ExcelApp.Quit();
        releaseObject(ExcelApp);
        releaseObject(workbooks);
        releaseObject(ExcelWorkBook);
        releaseObject(ExcelWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(ExcelRange);
    }
```

Раньше все что было в test() находилось в button3_Click и процесс завершался, а вот таким образом остается висеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел, правда не очень понимаю как это связано. dsTest dSet = new dsTest(); вот эта штука у меня была еще в глобальных переменных, убрал и все заработало. Не знаю почему в обработчике события это не мешало, а тут вдруг такое.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто:

1. Ты используешь Интероп.
2. Ты не освобождаешь некторые переменные которые должен освобождать

Я бы не советовал в принципе использовать интероп.

- Через интероп запросто можно оставлять запущенные процесы екселя
- вообще ексель необходимо что бы был установлен для работы с файлами иначе программа не будет работать
- код получается довольно сложный
- а так же главная проблема -- скорость. Он оооочень медленный.)

  Вот тебе линка которая все обьяснит более детально, а так же предложит альтернативные пути:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Если же хочется работать именно с интеропом... Лови костыль на закрывание екселя в любом случае. Сработает, даже, если ты пишешь кривой код и не освобождаешь нужные переменные.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

private Application _excelApp;

private void CloseExcelApp()
{
    int hWnd = _excelApp.Application.Hwnd;
    uint processID;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)hWnd, out processID);
    Process.GetProcessById((int)processID).Kill();
}
```