# Экспорт DataGridView в Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview

Пытаюсь выгрузить 2+ таблиц в excel, делаю так :

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView.RowCount - 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView.ColumnCount-1 ; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView[j, i].Value.ToString();

                }

            }

            for (int ii = 0; ii <= dataGridView2.RowCount - 2; ii++)
            {
                for (int jj = 0; jj <= dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; jj++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView2[jj, ii].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Первая таблица выгружается нормально, а вторая никак не хочет, что я делаю не так ?

Comment: xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] а где здесь i и j ? может нужно xlWorkSheet.Cells[ii + 1, jj + 1]?

Comment: так она заменит предыдущую таблицу, запишет новую таблицу на ее место

Comment: Это ясно, что заменит, но чему во втором блоке циклов должны быть равны i и j? по моему они вне области видимости будут

Comment: почему ? и как тогда сделать ? по идее, i и j указывают на место, где остановилась запись первой таблицы, теперь мне нужно продолжить с того места (где остановились) и записать вторую таблицу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

берешь либу отсюда:
[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

и закидаешь данные с датагрида в 2хмерный масив и вызываешь сейв метод. :)

Там же почитаешь про то, почему твой здешний путь (интероп) плох. :)

Comment: ответ еще проще : надо было во втором цикле сделать так :
 for (int ii = 0; ii <= dataGridView2.RowCount - 2; ii++)
            {
                for (int jj = 0; jj <= dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; jj++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[ii + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView2[jj, ii].Value.ToString();
j++;
                }
            }

Comment: Он использует интероп. А это мало того, что очень медленное взаимодействие, так еще и часто оставляет лишние запущенные сервисы в бекграунде, т.к. легко ошибится в коде и не освободить переменные которые нужно было освободить.. Про это написано по ссылке которую я дал.:) Потому: неа, не проще. Если ему помочь просто так как расписал это ты, это лишь добавит ему проблем в будущем. Мой же ответ его от проблем освобождает. Да еще и обьясняет минуса некоторых других путей взаимодействий.

Comment: @Lolidze , так что при взаимодействии с большими ексель файлами разница в скорости может достигать в 60 и больше раз :) А это серьезное преимущество почему мой ответ лучше чем твой :) И это если проигнорировать другие минуса. А если и их включить - то разница будет еще более колосальная.

Comment: ок, спасибо большое за ответ