# Эффективные способы работы с Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Работаю в консольных приложениях. у меня стоит Windows 10 и VS последняя актуальная версия. Кое как,  методом тыка и вдумчивого поиска, разобрался с элементарными задачами: прочитать данные в такой-то ячейке, записать данные в такую-то ячейку, и создать новую книгу.
Использовал при этом:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Для меня большая проблема состоит в том, что я не вижу документации для работы с этой библиотекой. Если вы считаете, что есть более эффективные способы работы с Excel через C#, то просветите меня. Буду рад, если вы понятно для меня изложите.

Comment: Посмотрите сначала справку по VBA

Comment: @алексей Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Если вам подошёл какой-либо ответ, то отметьте его как принятый. Если ни один не подошёл — то оставьте уточняющий комментарий, чем именно вам не подошёл ни один из ответов.

Answer (score 12):

Во-первых вам следует определиться, какой вам формат нужен: `.xls` или `.xlsx`. Они совершенно разные: `xls` — бинарный, а `xlsx` — это zip-архив XML файлов. Также, возможно, вам может подойти `ods` файл, который тоже представляет собой zip-архив XML файлов, но об этом ниже.

#### Office COM Interop

То о чём вы ведёте речь называется Office Interop. Иногда ещё к этому названию добавляют COM. Я сильно рекомендую его **не использовать**. Разве что только вы генерируете небольшие файлы на компьютере для себя. Почему?

1. Очень медленный.
2. Много утечек памяти. Ни в коем случае не используйте эту библиотеку для веб-сайтов или приложений, где на сервере генерируются файлы Office-форматов. У вас кончится оперативная память довольно быстро и сайт или приложение упадёт.

   Чтобы не быть голословным, могу сказать, что Microsoft сама [не рекомедует использовать свою же Office COM Interop для автоматизации](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office):

   > Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

   Что в вольном переводе значит:

   > Корпорация Майкрософт не рекомендует и не поддерживает, автоматизации приложений Microsoft Office с помощью автоматических, не-интерактивных клиентских приложений или компонентов (включая ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM и службы NT), потому что офис может показывать нестабильное поведение и/или взаимоблокировку (deadlock), когда офис работает в этой среде.
3. Требует наличия офиса определённой версии. На каждую машину, где будет работать ваше приложение.

---

Рассмотрю `xlsx` файлы. Вроде уже прошло время, когда ещё надо поддерживать Office 2003 и ниже.

#### Путаница с названием форматов

Некорректно называть этот формат Excel. Excel — это одна из программ пакета Microsoft Office. (*Также некорректно называть `docx`-файл `Word`*). Называть формат `xlsx` Excel — приблизительно то же самое, что называть формат HTML — Internet Explorer.

#### Office Open XML

Что следует из того, что это zip-архив XML файлов? Что это значит?

Это значит, что вы можете взять любой Open XML формат (все которые оканчиваются на `x`: `docx`, `xlsx`, `pptx` и т.д.), переименовать расширение на zip, открыть его. Затем можно посмотреть все нужные XML-файлы и можно даже попробовать их редактировать. (То же самое справедливо и для `ods`, но это `OpenDocument`-формат, а *не* `Open XML`!).

#### Стандарт Open XML

`xlsx`-файлы безусловно связаны с реализацией Microsoft. OpenXML форматы (все которые оканчиваются на `x`: `docx`, `xlsx`, `pptx` и т.д.) стали выходить после пакета офиса 2007 года. Microsoft опубликовало [спецификацию](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) в 2006 году, затем выпустило офис. А зачем Microsoft выпустило спецификацию? Для того, чтобы её реализовать мог *кто угодно*.

#### Трудности в работе с Open XML

> **Важное обновление.** Все нижеописанные трудности крайне успешно решаются с помощью бесплатного инструмента от Microsoft под названием [OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). Он позволяет
>
> - генерировать код для создания документа,
> - генерировать код превращения одного документа в другой,
> - валидировать документы с ошибками и показывать какие именно ошибки он содержит.

Дело в том, что стандарт Open XML мягко говоря, громоздкий (занимает 6546 страниц), поэтому его просто не осилишь просто чтением стандарта.

И с ним работать довольно тяжело. У вас есть объектная обёртка над различными тэгами XML. **НО:**

- При разработке ничто не подсказывает что и куда должно быть вложено. Вам приходится находить рабочие примеры и делать из них "винигрет" того, что работает.
- Основная трудность помимо того, что нет никакой подсказки до компиляции что с ним делать, что нет и никаких исключений и ошибок, если вы сгенерировали невалидную XML-структуру.
- Всё сильно усугляется тем, что офис просто не откроет ваш документ. Точнее откроет и выдаст "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened". То есть одна ошибка (вложили не тот элемент или чего-то не вложили) и даже гигантский документ не открывается.
- Вам приходится вникать в низкоуровневые детали того, как устроено хранение данных. То есть сама разработка сильно усложняется тем, что вам приходится писать код для казалось бы простых вещей. К примеру:

  - Здесь вы узнаете, что строковые значения ради производительности хранятся в специальной таблице (`SharedStringTable`) и при добавлении и новой строки добавляется всего лишь порядкой номер в этой таблице (к примеру в ячейке будет хранится `1`). То есть если вам надо добавить строковое значение в ячейку вам надо будет посмотреть в таблицу `SharedStringTable` есть ли там такая строка, и если нет — то создать запись в этой таблице, и вернуть новое число, если да — то взять порядковый номер.
  - Для того, чтобы даты просто добавить ячейку как дату, надо помнить что они хранятся как числа (OLE Date), но весь курьёз заключается в том, что есть тип `CellValues.Date`, который не работает. Далее надо будет добавить несколько секций стилей и тогда всё заработает. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31829959/1548895). Если вам ещё важен формат дат, то это тоже потребует времени разобраться, как именно хранятся форматы данных.
  - Если вам надо будет просто удалить строку (row) или столбец (column), то придётся все значения (ниже или правее) переносить вручную.

### Библиотеки, основанные на Open XML

В общем, если обернуть всё методами и потратить где-то 1-3 рабочих дня, то в целом можно и так работать. Чтобы избежать этих сложный вещей используйте уже готовые библиотеки, основанные на Open XML:

- [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

## Open Document Format

Помимо `xls` и `xlsx` существует также формат `ods`, который первоначально поддерживался в OpenOffice и затем LibreOffice. Cейчас форматы `Open Document` уже поддерживаются и Microsoft Office. Для этого работы с форматами `Open Document` существует библиотека AODL, для которой есть [Nuget-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AODL/) и [примеры](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL_examples).

Answer (score 4):

Для этих целей лучше использовать **OpenXML** так как **interop** штука тормозная+ требует наличия office (Правда, можно поставить халявный office SDK).

Голый **OpenXML** не очень приятный в использовании, поэтому для него существует удобная обертка **EPPlus**

Примеры и документация [тут](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Правда, есть ограничение:

Либа не поддерживает **EXCEL** формата 2003 года.

Вроде, формат 2003 года сохранялся в бинарном виде, а не в структуре XML.

Comment: благодарю всех за помощь, а есть ли литература по EPPlus на русском? я слабо понимаю на инглише, да и програмировать пока не умею. или может есть кто-то кто может мне на примере кода(желательно без лямбда выражений и LINq) показать эти работающие решения? задача выглядит так: на работе есть производственная программа, все данные записаны в Excel и надо по ним оптимизировать производство так чтобы была максимальная маржа. ну в общем самая типичная задача. глубочайших знаний по эксель мне не нужно, достаточно уметь считывать информацию в числовой массив и определять границы файла.

Answer (score 0):

Если работа с ексель файлами требует всего лишь работу с данными и в частности с данными на одной таблице/странице, я советовал бы не заморачиватся и просто вот этот скриптик использовать:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

В нем ты сразу работаешь с ексель файлом как с 2хмерным массивом ячеек. Минимум функционала.

Если хочется больше -- советую ClosedXML как обертка к OpenXML.
Так же по ссылке найдешь ответ на свой вопрос. В принципе, там написано то же, что написал Vadim Ovchinnikov. Просто другими словами + пример использования.