# c# - чтение Excel,oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Используется провайдер Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 для чтения файла Excel.
Прочиталось только 255 колонок. Гугл подсказывает не по теме.

код:

```
string ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"; Data Source={0}", filename);            DataSet ds = new DataSet("EXCEL");

OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
cn.Open();

string select = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, cn);
ad.Fill(ds);
DataTable tb = ds.Tables[0];

return tb;
```

UPD
выяснилось, что это ограничение Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
кто знает - изменилось ли что-то в старших версиях?

Comment: Использовать OleDb принципиально?

Comment: @Андрей лучше ведь обновить текущий софт чем добавлять что-то еще?

Comment: @Андрей а что можете порекомендовать вместо него?

Comment: Т.е вы поддерживаете существующий код? Ну тогда, конечно, надо вносить корректировки, но параллельно разрабатывать код, использующий другие технологии (если есть на это ресурсы). Как вариант - можно использовать несколько запросов, содержащие разные столбцы, если есть, конечно, какой-то столбец с уникальными значениями, с помощью которого чтобы потом можно было объединить результаты

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766599/6766879

Comment: Я что-то не  пойму зачем для чтения использовать ` Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB`, если можно сделать проще?

Comment: @Андрей попробовал ExcelDataReader - этот читает только 4 колонки (это как так вообще???)

Comment: @vvsibir, говоря про использование других технологий я имел ввиду примерно это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612436/218063

Comment: @Андрей спасибо, видел этот ответ - мне нужны оба формата xls и xlsx. В конце концов использовал NPOI

Answer (score 1):

Пробовал Interop Excel (очень медленно даже для таблицы 300х50 - около минуты), ExcelDataReader - не читал в нужном файле дальше 4й колонки.

Остановился на NPOI с http://npoi.codeplex.com/ - читает довольно шустро

вот код получения всех данных с первого листа:

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;


//................

    private DataTable GetFromExcel_NPOI(string filename)
    {
        XSSFWorkbook xssfwb = null;
        HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = null;

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(filename).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
                hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(file); // для старого формата другой класс
            else
                xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        }

        ISheet sheet = null;

        // берем первый лист
        if (xssfwb != null) sheet = xssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); 
        else sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0); // кол-во столбцов будем смотреть по первой строчке
        IEnumerator rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();

        int colCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;
        int rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum; 

        // создаем шапку - генерируем имена столбцов (эта таблица не содержит шапки)
        for (int c = 0; c < colCount; c++)
            dt.Columns.Add(string.Format("F{0}", c), typeof(string));

        rows.Reset(); // необязательно, но для страховки оставил
        while (rows.MoveNext())
        {
            IRow row = (IRow)rows.Current;
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            bool bEmptyRow = true; // это для того, чтобы пропускать пустые строки 
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
            {
                ICell cell = row.GetCell(i);

                if (cell != null)
                {
                    bEmptyRow = bEmptyRow && string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.ToString());
                    dr[i] = cell.ToString();
                }

            }
            if(!bEmptyRow) dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;

    }
```