# Как вставить данные из C# в excel

Tags: c#, excel

Пытаюсь вставить данные. Ошибок не вылетает, но и ничего и не записывает. На чтение работает на ура.

```
OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
opf.Filter = "Файл Excel|*.XLSX;*.XLS";
opf.ShowDialog();
string filename = opf.FileName;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook ExcelWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet;

ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false,
    false, 0, true, 1, 0);
ExcelWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
ExcelApp.Cells[7,7].Value =1;
```

Comment: [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612208/c-работа-с-excel)?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо изменить последнюю строку

```
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[7, 7].Value2 = 1;
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/277936)

Comment: @Jarvis_J почему не содержится решения?