# Ряд вопросов при работе с EXCEL таблицей через С# (interop)

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Задача: вытащить данные из строк таблицы минуя строки заголовков, пустые строки и т.п. и засунуть их в массивы обьектов для дальнейшей манипуляции.

Представлен набросок кода, с комментариями-вопросами, прошу если есть возможность дать свои рекомендации, т.к. только начал изучать С#.

```
    public static Drom_object[] ReadMassive(string path)
    {

        //По полученной ссылке от компонента OpenFileDialog
        //надо бы Считать файл таблицы xls полностью

        //Создаём приложение.
        Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Excel.Application();
        //Открываем книгу.                                                                                                                                                        
        Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        //Выбираем таблицу(лист).
        Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
        ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];


        //public int num_lines = read_number_of_lines_in document(); // прочитать общее количество строк в документе. каким методом можно сделать?


        // начинаем засовывать строчки из  таблицы в наши обьекты  Drom_object.

        //  public string global_category; - нам нужна строчка под глобальную категорию товара (запчасти от ДВС или кузовные и т.п.)

        // for(i = 0; i!=num_lines; i++)
        //  {

        //  string line  =  Excel.readline(i) // читаем строчку 

        //  if( колонны с А по M обьединены ) // если это так значит мы прочли заголовок (ДВС, стеклоподьемники и т.п.)
        //   { 
        //    global_category  = line;
        //    }
        //
        //   else {
        //     if( !line.Contains("наименование товара") and !line.IsEmpty() ) - строчки с заголовками и пустые мы не трогаем. а только те, что содержат сами позиции.
        //     {
        // раз строчка не пустая и не содержит заголовков и это не глобальная категория значит это строчка с товаром, начинаем ее разбирать

        // drom_massive[] = add.(new drom_object(columnA,columnB,columnC... etc)); 

        //Удаляем приложение (выходим из экселя) - ато будет висеть в процессах!
        ObjExcel.Quit();


        read_ok = true; // после того как наполнение закончено, поднимаем флаг
        return drom_massive; // Возвращаем наш массив объектов

    }
```

Comment: А обязательно требуется таким образом читать excel? Существуют библиотечки и с их помощью проще парсить документ. Вот тут они хорошо описаны: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612208/c-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-excel

Из своего опыта порекомендую посмотреть на EPPlus, к нему и примеры можно найти

Comment: а как его подключить? Вот я скачал архив что дальше, или можно как то подтянуть с гитхама через висуал студио?

Comment: Через nuget можно подключить

Comment: угу, уже разобрался)  видимо пакет и правда очень удобный. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если не требуется использовать именно ваш способ, а можно воспользоваться сторонними пакетами, то советую обратить внимание на этот вопрос: [C# работа с Excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612208/)

Из своего опыта порекомендую посмотреть на EPPlus. Мне показался удобным и простым для понимания