# Открытие файла эксель на языке C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, проблема такая, что не могу сделать запись в определенный файл, создается всегда новый файл.

```
string mySheet = @"C:\Desktop\book.xlsx";
//Add the Content sheet
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
ObjExcel.Visible = true;

//Книга.
ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
//Таблица.
ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];


ObjWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "ff";
```

Comment: А где у вас в этом коде запись в файл?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [c# Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / Сsv файлы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому нужно, вот решение

```
 var spreadsheetLocation = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Sample Data.xlsx");
        ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(spreadsheetLocation);
```