# Чтение Excel файла взять данные из колонки

Tags: c#

Возникла проблема с чтением excel файла, мне нужно взять данные из колонки с определенным именем.

```
            //ExcelDataReader works on binary excel file
            Stream stream = uploadfile.InputStream;
            //We need to written the Interface.
            IExcelDataReader reader = null;
            if (uploadfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
            {
                //reads the excel file with .xls extension
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            }
            else if (uploadfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                //reads excel file with .xlsx extension
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                //Shows error if uploaded file is not Excel file
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
                return View();
            }
            //treats the first row of excel file as Coluymn Names
            reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            //Adding reader data to DataSet()
            DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
            reader.Close();
            foreach (DataColumn column in result.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                if (column.ColumnName == "EAN")
                {

                }
            }
```

Но в таком случаи из файла читаются колонки из нулевой позиции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно прочесть на позицию ниже, но у меня не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как мне получить данные из этого столбца до самого конца?

Comment: Что за библиотека используется? Это явно не интеропт

Comment: Install-Package ExcelDataReader

Comment: Попробуйте https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/ . Он свежее и интуитивно понятен.

Answer (score 1):

Что то типа:

```
for (int i=0; i++; i<result.Tables[0].Columns.Count)
    {
        DataColumn column = result.Tables[0].Columns[i];
        if (column.ColumnName == "EAN")
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    console.WriteLine(row[i]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать:
[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134)

то можно просто взять и прочитать циклом все

```
csv.Rows[i][НомерНужнойКолонки]
```

сделав еще иф который проверяет существует ли такой номер в даной строке :)

Но нужно иметь ввиду что эта либа не умеет работать с ".xls" файлами