# Как разобрать txt файл?

Tags: c#

Есть txt файл со следующей информацией:

> 2 дно, 1800, непроницаемая
>   Вторая платформа, 3500, проницаемая
>   Верхняя палуба, 7500, непроницаемая

Нужно разобрать данные в массив/массивы, но сохранив их принадлежность - то есть не перемешивая (2 дно, 1800, непроницаемая), так как каждая строка описывает высоту и свойство конкретного объекта.
Считать построчно, каждое свойство объекта разделено запятыми, все они описывают название, положение и проницаемость объекта палуба. 
Как это организовать?

Comment: Кто вам такой ужасный формат придумал?...

Comment: Надеюсь, я правильно выделил форматирование?

Comment: Считать построчно, каждую строку разделить по запятым?

Comment: Считать построчно, каждое свойство объекта разделено запятыми, все они описывают название, положение и проницаемость объекта палуба.

Comment: ну то есть вы в курсе, что делать. Вперед, дерзайте :)

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается, считать файл средствами `System.IO` или разбить строку на массив через `split` или какая-то другая проблема? Приведите код ваших попыток. И уточните, что в результате должно быть - объект с этими свойствами или набор массивов, или что-то еще?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Можно считать весь файл в память, если он маленький:

```
        //1. считать все данные в память, если файл не большой
        var fileData = File.ReadAllLines("тут путь к файлу");
        foreach (var row in fileData)
        {
            var items = row.Split(",");
        }
```

Можно считывать построчно:

```
        //2. считать построчно
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("тут путь к файлу"))
        {
            while (sr.Read() > 0)
            {
                String row = sr.ReadLine();
                var items = row.Split(",");
            }
        }
```

И в том и в другом случае в объекте row будет содержаться массив из 3х строк. Далее его уже можно преобразовать в требуемый типизированный объект.

Еще можно воспользоваться сторонними библиотеками для парсинга, например [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading#reading-records). Но возможно это лишнее усложнение в вашей ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Этот формат данных называется CSV (Comma separated Value). Он довольно широко используется.

Вот здесь есть простой код с использованием внутренней библиотеки Visual Basic(это родная библиотека Visual Studio) которая считывает файл в двухмерный массив. Внешний массив - массив строк. Каждый внутренний массив - массив значений разделенных комой.

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Сложность чтения CSV заключается в том, что некоторые ячейки могут иметь внутри себя знак сепарации(кома в даном случае) и в таком случае вся ячейка должна обрамлятся в кавычки.

Другая сложность заключается в возможности того, что каждая ячейка внутри себя так же может иметь переход на следующую строку.

Так что в принципе я не советую мучится и делать собственную реализацию велосипеда CSV Reader-a с собственными костылями, а воспользоватся готовым решением. Тем более, что готовое решение является частью стоковых библиотек Visual Studio. Пример кода чтения в двухмерный массив можно найти по ссылке выше.

Comment: Забыта ссылка на пример с [библиотекой](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.2) VB?

Comment: ничего там не забыто. Там линк на проэкт в котором есть готовый CSV парсер который парсит в двухмерный масив. Даже кодить ничего не нужно.

Comment: _с использованием внутренней библиотеки Visual Basic(это родная библиотека Visual Studio)_ - в .NET есть единственная родная библиотека, способная разобрать csv - та, на которую я дал ссылку.

Comment: Ok, понял: внутри csv.cs используется `TextFieldParser`. Но, имхо, обертка над ним избыточна (он сам по себе парсер). Разбор xlsx-файлов в данном вопросе не нужен. И упоминание _внутренней библиотеки_ только сбивает с толку (до неё ещё докопаться нужно).