# C#. string[] в Файл Exсel

Tags: c#, excel

Еще не разобрался с библиотекой для работы с Excel. Но уже сегодня нужно срочно раскидать Готовый массив в готовый файл Excel. Массив изменяется в процессе выполнения программы и будет записываться несколько раз поэтому нужно после записи отступить на следующую строку и продолжить ряд.

Comment: Нууу... так дела не делаются. Предоставьте свои наработки.

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041021/how-to-write-some-data-to-excel-file-xlsx

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b) Там есть готовый рецепт для этой задачи.

Comment: рекомендую библиотеку epplus. вам понадобится epplus.dll. примеры кода можно в интернете надыбать https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started