# Как импортировать данные в 1С посредством C#?

Tags: c#, 1с

Есть некоторые данные которые подгружаются функциями API (небольшое веб приложение)

Эти данные нужно импортировать в 1С.
Подскажите как это сделать?
Ни разу этого не делал. 1С толком не знаю.
Может быть есть более гуманные способы импорта, напрямую в базу, которую использует 1С, но скорей всего нужно напрямую.
Мне нужна информация с нуля.

Comment: исходя из того что я знаю об 1с, самый простой способ будет заключаться в том что бы подготовить импортируемые данные в каком нибудь файле, а затем на 1с сделать *обработку* которая этот файл импортирует

Comment: ну этот вариант я тоже обдумывал, но проблема то в том, что я не знаю 1с и как там обработать этот файл подготовленный. Мне бы лучше сделать всё из C#

Comment: 1С как COM, но все равно потребуется знание 1С.

Comment: сторонню бд можно подключить к 1с и использовать её напрямую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то я видел реализацию того, как 1с выгружало свою базу данных в магазин на основе WASS CMS.

Там была следующая реализация:

1. В 1С генерился CSV файл который в последствии загружался в магазин через php cкрипт знающий структуру бд
2. выгружались нужные картинки через тот же php в нужную директорию

Не то что бы я прям в этом разбирался, но, думаю, это самое простое из возможных решений.
Работать с CSV в любом языке достаточно просто. Тем более, если там не будет никакой сложно отформатированной информации.

Скажем, можешь попробовать в шарпе генерить сцв при помощи 
[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

а потом в 1с дергать собственную функцию, которая будет импортировать данные как тебе нужно. На всякий случай советую использовать как разделитель не `,`, а какой-то извращенный знак вроде `ǂ` или `Ǽ` что бы тебе не нужно было реализовать полную реализацию обработки CSV на 1с по полной его спецификации. (спасет от отлавливания кавычек в случае если внутри ячейки есть делимитер [от перехода на следующую строку внутри ячейки, конечно же, не спасет!])

так же, предполагаю, что возможно где-то уже есть реализация обработчика цсв на 1с. Возможно, даже, с коробки. Но гарантий не даю.

---

Хотя повторюсь еще раз: сам я с 1с дела не имел и это все сугубо теоретически.

Comment: Достаточно полезный совет, спасибо! Буду пробовать!