# Парсинг *.csv в двумерный массив C#

Tags: c#

Необходимо прочитать csv файл так,чтобы каждая ячейка csv файла соответствовала ячейке в массиве.Находил способы прочитать в одномерный массив,где каждый элемент массива соответствует строке csv файла,но это не подходит.

Кода парсинга:'

```
  public static string[,] LoadCsv()
            {
                string filename = "C:\\Users\\mich1\\Desktop\\KDZ_3\\KDZ_3\\TEATP.csv";


                    string[,] mass = new string[300, 250]; // таблица для данных
                    int j = 0;
                    String line = String.Empty;
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        String[] parts_of_line = line.Split(',');
                        for (int i = 0; i < parts_of_line.Length; i++)
                        {
                            parts_of_line[i] = parts_of_line[i].Trim();
                            mass[j, i] = parts_of_line[i].Trim();
                        }
                        j++;
                    }

                return mass;

                }'
```

Метод вызова:'

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ParsingFromToCsv.LoadCsv()[1,0]);
        }'
```

[image: Пример csv файла]

Comment: Опишите проблему, что не получается? Покажите Ваш код, что сделано на данный момент?)

Comment: Покажите пример этого вашего csv файла. И что вы успели написать, для правки вопроса нажмите под тегом `править`.

Comment: Ну все же нужно прочитать на форуме "мануал", как правильно задавать вопросы, чтобы получить ответ, а не минусы

Comment: При вызове array[0,1] на экран выводится  "Уголок дедушки Дурова Государственное бюджетное учреждение культуры города Москвы «Театр «Уголок дедушки Дурова» и тд" Здесь "Уголок дедушки Дурова" и "Государственное бюджетное учреждение культуры города Москвы «Театр «Уголок дедушки Дурова»" -разные ячейки файла csv. Необходимо организовать вывод только "Уголок дедушки Дурова" при вызове array[1,0]. Код показать не могу,потому что не до конца понимаю как его добавить сюда,он больше 500 символов,а тут ограничение.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3):

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsv(string path, char separator = ';', int skip = 0, Encoding enc = null)
{
    return File
        // читаем файл построчно
        .ReadAllLines(path, enc ?? Encoding.Default)
        // пропускаем строки, если надо (возможно есть заголовки)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
        // разделяем строку
        .Select(l => l.Split(separator));
}
```

Вызов функции напишите сами )

Comment: Только лучше переписать через стрим. Чтоб уж юзать генераторы по полной. Вдруг там CSV на гигабайт.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю ,что пустые ячейки он пропускает?

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК, судя по вопросу, там мало строк ) `string[300, 250]`

Comment: @TheGreatNeo-NEO-, скорее пустые строки

Comment: Спасибо,помогло

Comment: Как можно отвечать не зная какой файл у человека? Полная спецификация CSV предполагает возможность наличия делимитера внутри ячеек и возможность перехода на следующую строку внутри ячеек (в обеих случаях ячейка по сторонам выделяется кавычками) и возможность имения в такой вот сложной ячейке внутри так же кавычек, которые должны тоже обрабатыватся. Ни в одном из перечисленных случаев даный код не сработает. Лучше использовать готовую внутреннюю библиотеку VisualBasic для этого т.к. там из коробки поддержка всех этих случаев имееется.

Comment: Вопрос поставил на закрытие как дубликат, там есть решение через вижуал бейсик готовое, которое и работает сразу с CSV файлом как с двухмерным масивом. И на чтение, и на запись есть функционал, а так же имеется полная поддержка спецификации CSV так что проблем гарантированно не возникнет.

Comment: но вообще за старания поставил плюс. :)