# Экспорт таблицы listView в Excel с помощью библиотеки ClosedXML

Tags: c#

При экспорте в Excel файл из listView каким образом можно сделать что бы в Excel был весь текст с лева на право. Использовал данную статью для написания экспорта в Excel: [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-excel-xlsx-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B)

```
private void excell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel mon|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                SaveExel(sfd.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("Ваши данные успешно сохранены.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
    public void SaveExel(string filepath)
    {
        Excel xl = new Excel(); //создаем инстанс
        try
        {
            xl.AddRow(listView1.Columns.OfType<ColumnHeader>().Select(x => x.Text).ToArray());
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                var arr = item.SubItems.OfType<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();

                xl.AddRow(arr);
            }

            xl.FileSave(filepath);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

---

бИБЛИОТЕКА Excel

```
public class Excel
    {
        public List<List<string>> Rows = new List<List<string>>();

        public void FileOpen(string path)
        {

            var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
            var ws1 = workbook.Worksheet(1);

            foreach (var xlRow in ws1.RangeUsed().Rows())
            {
                Rows.Add(new List<string>());

                foreach (var xlCell in xlRow.Cells())
                {
                    var formula = xlCell.FormulaA1;
                    var value = xlCell.Value.ToString();

                    string targetCellValue = (formula.Length == 0) ? value : "=" + formula;

                    Rows[Rows.Count - 1].Add(targetCellValue);
                }
            }
        }

        public void FileSave(string path)
        {
            CreateDirIfNotExist(path, true);

            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                var workSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");

                for (int row = 0; row < Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < Rows[row].Count; col++)
                    {
                        var cellAdress = GetExcelPos(row, col);

                        if (Rows[row][col].StartsWith("="))
                        {
                            workSheet.Cell(cellAdress).FormulaA1 = Rows[row][col];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            workSheet.Cell(cellAdress).Value = Rows[row][col];
                        }
                    }
                }

                wb.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }

        public void AddRow(params string[] cells)
        {
            Rows.Add(cells.ToList());
        }

        public static string GetExcelPos(int row, int cell)
        {
            char[] alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

            int count = cell / 26;
            string alphResult = string.Empty;

            if (count > 0)
            {
                alphResult = alph[count] + alph[count % 26].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                alphResult = alph[cell].ToString();
            }

            return alphResult + (row + 1);
        }

        private void CreateDirIfNotExist(string dirPath, bool removeFilename = false)
        {
            if (removeFilename)
            {
                dirPath = Directory.GetParent(dirPath).FullName;
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            }
        }

        internal void AddRow(IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Результат который должен быть: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Результат на данный момент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну вы пример покажите, как вы хотите, чтобы данные экспортировались

Comment: @tym32167 вроде все написал

Comment: я имел ввиду какой вам надо результат - то есть как эксель таблица в конце выглядеть должна

Comment: @tym32167 понял вас, щас выложу скрин

Comment: что то я не понял, в чем разницв между скринами?

Comment: @tym32167 нету выравнивания по левому краю, а мне нужно именно это. Кст в самой программе все выровнено по левому краю

Comment: так вам форматирование надо настроить?  Тогда надо идти к [автору библиотеки](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50552005#50552005)