# Работа с SQLite и ClosedXml

Tags: c#, sqlite, closedxml

Мне нужно вытащить все из базы данных в Exel файл, работаю с SQLite and ClosedXml. Работаю по шаблону, заранее созданный шаблон, нужно все вывести. Все что пока сделал, не работает, один раз добавляет и потом Exception Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен.
Мой код:

```
string query = "select * from "+bdName;
        string fileOut = @".\Books\finish.xlsx";
        var template = new XLTemplate(@".\Books\TemplateExel.xlsx");

        if (bdName != null)
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, DB);
            SQLiteDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {

                    var dbCust = new DbTemplate();


                    dbCust.Date = dataReader.GetString(1);
                    dbCust.Name = dataReader.GetString(2);
                    dbCust.NameOperation = dataReader.GetString(3);
                    dbCust.Count = dataReader.GetString(4);

                    //первый вариант
                    template.AddVariable(dbCust);
                    template.Generate();
                    template.SaveAs(fileOut);

                    //второй вариант   
                    //template.AddVariable("Date", data_picker);
                    //template.AddVariable("Name", txt_name.Text);
                    //template.AddVariable("NameOperation", txt_nameOperation);
                    //template.AddVariable("Count", txt_count.Text);

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если взять библиотеку-враппер на ClosedXml отсюда:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134)

То код будет приблизительно:

```
string query = "select * from "+bdName;
string fileOut = @".\Books\finish.xlsx";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, DB);
SQLiteDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

Excel xl = new Excel(); //создаем инстанс

var сolumnNames = ReadColumnNames();
var allRows = ReadAllRows(rdr, ColumnNames.Count() );

xl.AddRow(сolumnNames);

foreach (var row in allRows)
{
    xl.AddRow(row);
}

xl.FileSave(fileOut); //сохраняем файл





public List<string> ReadColumnNames(SQLiteDataReader rdr)
{
    var columns = new List<string>();

    for(int i=0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
        columns.Add( rdr.GetName(i) );

    return columns;
}

public List<string> ReadAllRows(SQLiteDataReader rdr, int columnsNum)
{
    var rez = new List<string[]>();

    while (rdr.Read(rdr, columnsNum)) 
    {
        rez.Add(ReadSingleRow(rdr, columnsNum));
    }

    return rez;
}

public string[] ReadSingleRow(SQLiteDataReader rdr, int columnsNum)
{
    string[] rez = new string[columnsNum]();

    for(int i=0; i<= columnsNum)
    {
        rez[i] = rdr.GetString(0);
    }

    return rez;
}
```

Код писал в блокноте и не проверял так что могут быть мелкие ошибки.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, скорее завтра отпишу. Спасибо!

Comment: Ошибки исправил. Код работает. Но мне нужно по шаблону чтобы все вывело. Делаю я для своей работы, чтобы не писать руками на листке. Пример я брал от сюда https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/ru/Quick-start

Comment: Я писал разработчикам, но они мне ответили только, что нужно установить драйвер ODBC и прислали что через саму Excel подключить и вывести. Но мне нужно все программно делать. Я им писал, они больше не ответили. У меня выводит, но только первую запись, а потом ошибка, что не может добавить с этим же ключом

Comment: Не свосем понимаю что за вопрос и что за схема. Что значит "по шаблону что бы все вывело"? Но, задание оригинального вопроса, судя по всему, я, все таки, решил.

Comment: Если "шаблон" это ранее созданный документ, то используя ту же библиотеку открывай тот же документ в самом начале, а потом делай то же самое.

Comment: Вчера хотел попробовать, уснул. Короче у меня есть свойства, которые соответствуют шаблону вот скрин https://ibb.co/2ttLDZN, вот мне нужно из базы заполнить по шаблону. Сейчас буду пробовать через твой способ добавить.

Comment: думаю можно заполнять моим способом делая 3 пустых первых строки, а потом добавлять уже через чистый функционал ClosedXML твой заголовок что бы вышел этот шаблон