# Изменить файл csv внутри программы C#

Tags: c#, winforms, interop

Всем доброго времени суток!
С приложением windows Forms пока сложно. 
Создал консольное приложение
Я спарсил CSV файл, теперь хочу **все данные записать в один массив string**, просто каждую итерацию у меня значение в str записывается заново.
Пробовал через цикл for, но у меня ничего не вышло.

```
            string[] str = {};
            string[] str_result = {};
            using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\Хроматограф\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\История обменов.csv"))
            {
                int i = 0;
                tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                tfp.SetDelimiters(",");
                while (!tfp.EndOfData)
                {
                    str = tfp.ReadFields();
                }
            }
```

Файл CSV с данными формата`2019-08-25 12:46:57.79, 1330206, 0.00076094, 487, 0.0000038, 640001, RUB, BTC, QIWI, Fast_BTC_Change, 12AE8f, purchase, confirm_payment`.

Comment: csv не стандартизирован. Так что и через запятую допустимый вариант. Но можно просто открыть как обычный текст. заменить запятые на точку с запятой и сохранить обратно.

Comment: CSV - **Comma** separated values - значения, разделенные запятыми.

Comment: @srvr4vr может и не стандартизирован, но спеки есть [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) и там не все так просто, как хотелось бы.

Comment: С этим разобрался, теперь мне надо всё это добро добавить в массив string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователь @tym32167 подсказал такое решение моей задачи

```
 var str = new List<string>();
        using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\Veles\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\Финансовый отчёт пп.csv"))
        {
            int i = 0;
            tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            tfp.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!tfp.EndOfData)
            {
                str.AddRange(tfp.ReadFields());
            }
        }
```

Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь!

Answer (score 0):

> всё данные находятся в одной ячейке

Формат CSV подразумевает, что содержимое ячеек таблицы отделяется друг от друга символами запятой или другим символом. По сути каждая строчка таблицы в CSV, это просто одна строка. Поэтому Excel и показывает данные таким образом.

Если Вас это совсем не устраивает, существует 2 варианта решить Вашу проблему:

- Вам нужно распарсить CSV и сохранить данные в Excel (например через
  `Interop` или [OfficeOpenXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648641/c-sharp-convert-csv-to-xls-using-existing-csv-file)). Только на выходе будет уже не `csv`,
  а `xlsx`;
- Замените разделяющие запятые на символы табуляции. Тогда каждая колонка будет отображаться как положено. Однако, это костыль и его работоспособность в Excel старше 2003 не гарантируется.

Comment: Спасибо, начальный шаг помог мне. Я понял с чего мне надо начать, распарсил CSV, теперь надо всё это дело объединить в массив, и мне снова нужен совет.

Comment: Тогда задайте отдельный вопрос. В вопросе укажите что и как пытаетесь делать и что не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Я создавал тему:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134)

Если использовать класс из этой темы, то выйдет код:

```
Csv csv = new Csv(); //создаем инстанс читалки; Если нестандартный делимитер то new Csv('|');
csv.FileOpen("c:\\file1.csv"); //открываем файл

var rez = scv.Rows[0];// в rez записаны все ячейки из первой строчки csv как и было нужно
```

Дальше меняешь нужную ячейку и сейвишь методом сейв.

Если я правильно понял изначальную задачу, то это весь код который нужно написать в принципе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Переделаю, что я написал.
Почти правильно, но ответ хороший, из него я что-нибудь под себя состругаю))
У меня есть CSV формат строки указал в описании, я хочу чтобы в var rez записалось n значений. На выходе мне нужен массив с данными например 50 строк, из которых я могу взять данные и провести над ними манипуляции.

Comment: Сначала файлы с кириллицей не открывались, баг какой то, теперь всё нормально. Поюзал немного Вашу либу перед сном, мне всё понравилось, то что надо. Andrew спасибо!

Comment: тогда с тебя ̶л̶а̶й̶к̶ ̶и̶ ̶п̶о̶д̶п̶и̶с̶к̶а̶   проголосовать за полезность и отметить ответ правильным

Comment: Серьёзно круто) после такого хочется изучать программирование чтобы писать что то полезное и помогать людям, я вот тоже хочу программку эту запилить чтобы люди курс биткоина не ломали) Ответ пометил верным, голоса мои пока не учитываются, у меня меньше 15 репутиии)

Comment: Хотя это решения позволяет работать только с одной строкой, то есть и в моём варинте тоже самое, я могу записать значение одной строки и как загнать значения в var rez непонятно. Туда только 1 строка влезает, а дальше программа выдаёт ошибку System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Индекс за пределами диапазона"

Comment: Убрал галочку так как в решении моей задачи мне это не помогло.

Comment: `var rez = scv.Rows` вместо `var rez = scv.Rows[0]` позволяет работать со всеми строками.

Comment: Или сразу обращайся к `scv.Rows` c нужными индексами строка/ячейка. Например `scv.Rows[10][10]` возвратит тебе значение  11 ячейки 11й строки.

Comment: Этого я не пробовал, я просто начал делать через цикл for, на выходе получается List<string>, который придётся через String.Join(" ", List.ToArray), преобразовывать чтобы записать в массив string, но тогда получится тоже самое, что было в CSV

Comment: Тут суть в том, что мне надо сразу много данных, обратиться к одной строке я могу, к одной ячейке я могу обратиться, но мне нужно все 13 столбцов записать на 10 или 50 строк, и уже этот массив данных обработать

Comment: для чего тебе преобразовывать в string[] если это УЖЕ List<string> ? Скорее всего ты сам не разобрался с тем что ты имеешь и тем что ты хочешь получить и тем как ты хочешь обработать. Сначала обдумай все, а потом создай новый вопрос где опишешь что имеешь, что ты хочешь сделать с данными и что не получается.

Comment: Преобразовывать это нужно для того, чтобы в массив записать, чтобы у меня не одна строчка там хранилась, в этом и есть изначальная суть вопроса - "как записать много строк, а не одну строку". Одну строку я могу записать, а много строк - у меня не получается записать в один массив.

Comment: У меня в этом списке больше 13 значений не хранится, поэтому я и хочу их записать в один массив

Comment: изучи все методы из моей библиотеки, там такой функционал есть: `xl.AddRow("asdf","asdffffff","5");` и пример кода есть у меня в ответе-ссылке. И как ни странно, название метода говорит само за себя.... Изучи ответ и попробуй с ним разобраться перед тем как задавать новый...