# Как реализовать отступ строк в цикле выгрузка данных их C# в Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, interop

Помогите, никак не могу понять как сделать шаг при экспорте таблицы из datagridview в excel. Т.е. у меня есть таблица которую надо сделать как личное дело.  и чтобы каждое новое дело начиналось с отсупом в 5 сток есть такой код

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
        ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"1.xlsx");
        ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1]; 
        ObjExcel.Visible = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
            {
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 4, 1] = "ФИО: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 5, 1] = "Дата рождения: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 6, 1] = "Пол: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 7, 1] = "Паспортные данные: ";
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 8, 1] = "Кем выдан: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "";
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 9, 1] = "Когда выдан: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "";
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 10, 1] = "Серия/номер: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[8].Value.ToString() + "/" + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 11, 1] = "Тип паспорта: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 12, 1] = "Прописка: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 13, 1] = "Проживание: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 14, 1] = "Напраление подготовки: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                ObjExcel.Cells[j + 15, 1] = "Курс: " + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                Excel.Range oRange = (Excel.Range)ObjWorkSheet.Cells[j + 1, 8];
                float Left = (float)((double)oRange.Left);
                float Top = (float)((double)oRange.Top);
                var foto = "C:\\foto\\" + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + ".jpg";
                var nofoto = "C:\\foto\\nofoto.png";

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(foto))
                {
                    ObjWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(foto, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, 113, 151);
                }
                else
                {
                    ObjWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(nofoto, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, 113, 151);
                }

            }
```

Comment: вы бы хоть скрин приложили. Что значит отступ? Смещение ячеек? Пробелы? Табуляции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было "простым" сделал оператор с несколькими условиями `for (int i=0,y=0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount & y < calc; i++, y+=16)`

Answer (score 0):

Если брать за основу библиотеку из ответа: [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134)

```
Excel xl = new Excel();
xl.FileOpen("c:\\file1.xlsx");


for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
{
    string[] humanInformation = GetSingleRow(dataGridView1.Rows[j]);

    xl.AddRow(humanInformation); //записываешь строку даннных

    //делаем отступ в 5 строк
    for (int i =1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        xl.AddRow("");
    }
}

xl.FileSave("c:\\file2.xlsx"); //сохраняем файл
```

метод для сбора информации:

```
public string[] GetSingleRow(DataGridRow row)
{
    var foto = $"C:\\foto\\{row.GetCellVal(1)}.jpg";
    var nofoto = $"C:\\foto\\nofoto.png";

    List<string> singleRow = new List<string>();

    singleRow.Add($"ФИО: {row.GetCellVal(1)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Дата рождения: {row.GetCellVal(2)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Пол: {row.GetCellVal(3)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Паспортные данные:");
    singleRow.Add($"Кем выдан: {row.GetCellVal(5)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Когда выдан: {row.GetCellVal(6)}";
    singleRow.Add($"Серия/номер: {row.GetCellVal(8)}/{row.GetCellVal(7)}";
    singleRow.Add($"Тип паспорта:  {row.GetCellVal(9)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Прописка:  {row.GetCellVal(10)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Проживание:  {row.GetCellVal(11)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Напраление подготовки:  {row.GetCellVal(14)}");
    singleRow.Add($"Курс:  {row.GetCellVal(12)}");

    return singleRow.ToArray();
}

public static class DataGridRowExtension
{
    public string GetCellVal(DataGridRow row, int cellIndex)
    {
        return row.Cells[cellIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Вставку фото же нужно будет реализовать через расширение класса на который я сослался через методы ClosedXML.

Comment: А как быть если используешь библиотеку Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Использовать интероп - плохо. Почему плохо -- написано по ссылке которую я дал на начале своего ответа. Заодно можешь прямо сейчас проверить сколько инстансов екселя висят у тебя в таск менеджере пока ты тестировал и разрабатывал программу свою. Уверен, не меньше 7 штук висит :)

Comment: С моим количеством оперативки и процессором хоть 100 пусть висит

Comment: все что в моем коде было представленно было рабочим. только надо было чтобы делал отступ для каждой записи а не ложил ее друг на друга

Comment: А еще немасштабируемым, негибким и очень плохочитабельным. Собственно из-за отсутствия гибкости твоего кода ты и не сумел сделать вот те самые отступы. :) Безусловно там можно сделать отступы.... Вот только это сложно и костыльно и еще больше снизит читабельность и без того нечитабельного кода.

Comment: Например, можешь все данные записывать в двухмерный массив в одном цикле. А потом во втором цикле вставлять уже в ексель файл через интероп с `i+=5` в `for`-е из этого двухмерного массива. Ужасное решение, но сработает так как бы ты хотел этого.

Comment: То что ты в последнем варианте предложил не может работать. Это задаст шаг по масиву или гриду в 5 строк. ClosedXML так и не смог разобраться

Comment: про циклы не пашет вот пример `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)                                
            {
                fio = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                date = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

                for (int j = 0; j < calc; j += 16)
                {
                    ObjExcel.Cells[j + 4, 1] = fio;
                    ObjExcel.Cells[j + 5, 1] = date;
                }

            }`

Comment: Но он затирает старые данные т.е. берет 1 человека иподставляет на всю таблицу потом грбо говоря стирает и подставляет 2 человека в эти же места

Comment: Как минимум по ClosedXML в представленном коде не находит он Excel xl = new Excel(); хотя и using ClosedXML.Excel;  прописан

Comment: потому что ты мою библиотеку не подключил. Потому и не находит ексель. Закинь себе в проэкт класс Excel с гитхаба.

Comment: А по поводу "Ужасное решение" -- оно будет работать 100%. Если ты не можешь это реализовать - то это вопрос твоих умений, а не нерабочести подхода.

Comment: Спасибо за направоение в русло, решил задачу по другому `for (int i=0,y=0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount & y < calc; i++, y+=16)`