# Приходят пустые данные при импорте из Excel

Tags: c#

Нужно сделать импорт из файла `excel`. По клику выполняю этот код:

```
        private string pathToFile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/DataGridView.xls";
        private void btnImportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String name = "Sheet1";
            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            pathToFile +
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            bsClients.DataSource = data;
        }
```

Вот скрин дебага. Data пустая. В чём модет быть дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также прикрепляю Excel файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если развернуть Data, что внутри?

Comment: Пустой объект, ничего нет(

Comment: Проверьте переменную `pathToFile`. Возможно, вам нужен обратный слеш (`"\DataGridView.xls"`) или формат файла `.xlsx`

Comment: Проверил переменную, да, действительно был обратный слэш, но после изменения всё равно пустой объект(
Также пробовал сохранить файл в расширении .xlsx, но при чтении возникает ошибка. Поэтому использую .xls формат

Comment: используй библиотеку с этой ссылки. Разберешся значительно быстрее чем с oleDB. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/Как-просто-работать-с-открыть-изменить-сохранить-excel-xlsx-csv-файлы

Comment: Спасибо)
Я попробую и отпишусь в комментарии)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось через использование кастомной либы [ссылка на github репозиторий](https://github.com/ukushu/DataExporter)
Просто скопировал себе код 'Excel.cs' класса и использовал его методы.
В Readme человек всё хорошо описал, всё понятно)))