# Сохранить данные из WPF DataGrid в CSV

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс примерно такого содержания:

```
abstract class AbstractDataFile
{
    public abstract string filePath { set; get; }
    public abstract string fileName { get; }
    public abstract long inOffset { get; }
    public abstract long outOffset { get; }
    public abstract string Type { get; }
    public abstract DateTime FileDateTime { get; }
    public abstract TimeSpan Duration { get; }
    public abstract double? Temp{ get; }        
    public abstract uint? sourceId{ get; }
    ......
}
```

Ещё с кучей полей.
В результате работы фабрики я получаю ObservableCollection
которая привязана к datagrid :

```
ObservableCollection<AbstractDataFile> abstractFiles = new ObservableCollection<AbstractDataFile>();
dataGridView1.ItemsSource = abstractFiles;
```

Но при помещении в data grid экземпляров класса производных от AbstractDataFile я скрываю некоторые поля к примеру:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="File_Path" Binding="{Binding filePath}" IsReadOnly="True" **Visibility="Collapsed"**/>
```

Так как полный путь бывает длинным, да и пользователю путь не интересен. Но путь нужен при других манипуляциях типа копирования, удаления файлов и тд. Поэтому он как бы есть, но юзер его не видит. Также есть ещё несколько подобных полей чисто технического назначения.

Появилась задача сохранять всё что сделал пользователь с данными в datagridview в файл csv.
пытаюсь это решить так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = dataGridView1.Items[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                var column = dataGridView1.Columns[j];

                var cell = column.GetCellContent(item);

                Debug.WriteLine(cell);

            }
        }
```

cell - всегда null.

Или так:

```
            foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Items)
        {
            foreach (var prop in row.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                sw.Write(prop.GetValue(row, null)?.ToString() + ";");
            }
        }
```

В этом случае в файл попадают все скрытые поля, не сохраняется сортировка столбцов и тд.
В любом из приведённых выше вариантов я получаю экземпляр класса производного от AbstractDataFile. Хотя мне нужно получить именно то, что видит пользователь на datagridview.
Вариант с выделением всех ячеек datagrid и последующим копированием в буфер обмена не подходит.
Как получить данные именно с datagridview, а не с объекта который к нему привязан?
Для упрощения представим что все строки уже отрисованы.

Comment: Сохранять надо коллекцию `abstractFiles`, кот. является источником для отображаемых данных, а не "крутить" визуализацию в DGV. Отделите мысленно (а лучше архитектурно) слой визуализации от данных и сохраняйте данные.

Comment: @Bulson а если нужно сохранить сортировку в столбцах. Или сортировку расположения самих столбцов в выходном CSV. Тогда как быть?

Comment: Сортировка и расположение столбцов относится к слою визуализации (View) => относится к настройкам UI и к данным не имеет никакого отношения => следует сохранять отдельно от данных, как банальные настройки. Еще раз повторяю, нужно делить прогу на слои, почитайте про MVP, MVC, MVVM

Comment: @Bulson MVP, MVC, MVVM это конечно хорошо, спору нет. Но вот представьте что вам нужно накидать приложение, которое бы имело такой функционал. К слову Битриксы, 1С и тд умеют такое при выгрузке. и я думаю их создатели знали про  MVP, MVC, MVVM, но всё же реализовали такое.

Answer (score 0):

1. Создай метод который конвертирует твой обьект в массив стрингов в нужном порядке
2. Возьми колекцию обьектов и циклом пройдись по ней

   2.1 конвертация обьекта в массив строк

   2.2 всунуть массив строк в обьект сохраняюзий цсв как строку

Использовать можно библиотеку взятую отсюда, она идеально подойдет под твои задачи:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

для считывания делаешь то же самое, только в обратном порядке.

Comment: создать метод который конвертирует объект в строку в нужном порядке. А если порядок меняется пользователем, то придётся делать через dispalyindex?

Comment: если порядок входных данны меняется пользователем то делаешь то же самое что делается в экселе при импорте данных - при импорте дай пользователю возможность напрямую указывать какие данные хранятся в каком столбце.