# Не удается закрыть Excel в диспетчере задач

Tags: c#, excel

После создания объекта Excel не удается его закрыть: он также висит диспетчере задач:

```
 Excel.Application ObjWorkExcel = new Excel.Application();
 Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Add();
 Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];
 ObjWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = // Заполнение документа;
```

Пробовал закрыть различными способами:

```
  ObjWorkExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
  ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Close();
  ObjWorkExcel.Quit();
  ObjWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
   

  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ObjWorkExcel);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ObjWorkBook);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ObjWorkSheet);
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ObjWorkExcel);
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Сработал только способ Process.kill, однако тогда закрываются все открытые экселевские документы, что мне не подходит. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему

Comment: То есть Вы пытаетесь убить Excel, не закрыв документы, которые открыты в Excel?

Comment: И ещё, что именно висит в диспетчере задач? Процесс EXCEL.EXE?

Comment: Имя процесса "excel". Я пробовал закрывать "по старшинству" сначала лист, потом книгу, потом приложение эксель

Comment: Но, если Вы всё закрываете, почему ожидаете, что экселевские документы останутся открыты?

Comment: здесь описаны различные способа работы с эксель файлами без открывания окна экселя https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b

Answer (score -1):

Закиньте все в Try Catch
И в конце сделайте:

```
            finally
            {
                wb?.Close(false, filePath);

            if (xlSheets != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheets);
            if (excel != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
            if (wb != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
            }
```

Comment: у парня проблема в том, что он хочет работать с эксель файлами с закрытыми инстансами экселя. То есть на самом деле это не решение проблемы, хоть и ответ на заголовок самого вопроса. Правильное решение проблемы - перестать пользоваться интеропом.

Comment: Разве? Прочитав выше написанное я нигде не заметил, что человек пытается работать с эксель файлами с закрытыми инстансами.

Comment: "Сработал только способ Process.kill, однако тогда закрываются все открытые экселевские документы, что мне не подходит." То есть он пытается закрыть эксели и при этом продолжать работать с самими документами используя интероп. Смешно, но факт)