# Копирование данных из Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Для  работы с excel использую библиотеку `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Необходимо копировать большие объемы данных. С ~67к строками мой мобильный i7 возился минут 15(прямой проход по строкам). Вопрос в скорости работы. Целевой же компьютер - Celeron 2ГГц. При использовании этой стандартной библиотеки открывается сам excel.  Возможно ли иначе работать с файлами excel?  Едва ли с Celeron'ом потоки  будут хорошей идеей...

UPD1. [Здесь](https://github.com/ukushu/DataExporter/blob/master/Excel.cs) по ссылке от Andrew  в комментариях взял класс для [*быстрой* обработки файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-excel-xlsx-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B/560134#560134). В итоге только при чтении файла в 14 МБ либа  жрёт почти 1 ГБ(!). Либо я дурак, либо лыжи не едут...

```cs
Excel xl = new Excel(); 
xl.FileOpen(<путь к файлу>);
```

Comment: здесь куча вариантов того как работать с екселем описано https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134

Comment: @Andrew, формат файла  - xlsb...)

Comment: Почему эксель, как вы такую кучу строк туда закачиваете? В каком формате у вас исходные данные?

Comment: @aepot, исходный формат, как сказал  выше, xlsb. Данные были выкачены из БД.  Но суть в другом:  как эту кучу быстро  обрабатывать)  Да, мне  тоже  не  нравится, что это в excel,но что делать )

Comment: Вы можете интеропом открыть файл, сохранить как CSV, и далее работать с CSV. А вообще из юазы данных можно SQL запросом данные доставать. И та штука, которая вам эксель файл делает, наверняка умеет CSV.

Comment: соглашусь, самым простым вариантом будет пересохранить файл а потом обрабатывать цсв.

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю, что в БД с этим проще работать. Но что имеем по факту.
при конвертации в csv летит кириллица

Comment: при конвертации в csv летит кириллица -- вот с этой проблемой и работай

Comment: Ну уж кодировку то можно вылечить не прибегая к экселю. Кстати, а куда именно она летит? Можно подробнее?

Comment: Та абракадабра или ??????. Если абракадабра, то можно восстановить. Создайте отдельный вопрос с примером данных из файла и кодом, как именно вы его читаете, ну и скриншот, как выглядит.

Comment: Выяснил, что при сохранении в формате "CSV (разделители-запятые)" (все еще через сам excel)  данные сохраняются корректно. Осталось  понять, какой  это формат в Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat - указателе формата при сохранении файла. Обожаю microsoft и  их названия)

Comment: Допустим, можно  конвертировать исходный файл в csv. Но из него данные надо  перегнать так же в xlsb. Если же итоговый файл конвертировать в csv, а затем   обратно, то все форматирование тоже летит - не есть хорошо.  Замкнутый круг какой-то

Comment: если важны не только данные, а и форматирование - то тогда ищи nuget для работы с xlsb. Интероп точно не тот способ которым можно обрабатывать данные быстро.