# помогите исправить код для WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

у меня программа считывает данные таблицы Excel и записывает все в один массив, А мне надо, чтоб каждую строчку в отдельный массив.

И подключить кнопку(button1)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using OfficeOpenXml;

namespace Corrol
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private double[,] excelTable;
        private int totalRows = 0;
        private int totalColumns = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult res = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

                if (res == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName));

                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns];
                    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= totalRows; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());
                        List<string> list = row.ToList<string>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                        {
                            excelTable[rowIndex - 1, i] = Convert.ToDouble(list[i].Replace('-', ','));

                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(excelTable[i, j]) + "     ";

                        }
                        richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Файл не выбран");
                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Вынесите код в отдельный метод, и вызывайте его и из меню, и из кнопки. Гениально, не правда ли? А по поводу массивов - не понятно, что вам нужно. И самое главное - зачем?

Comment: Например в документе 3 строчки по 3 столбца, в каждой ячейке цифра. Код который у меня считывает это и заносит все в один массив, а мне надо чтоб каждая строка, заносилась в отдельный массив(новый)

Comment: Окей, а зачем это нужно, что значит новый массив? Массив массивов, список массивов, переменные разные? Что именно? Чем вас текущий массив не устраивает? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: мне это нужно, чтоб потом выявлять корреляцию. Но мб я не в правильном направлении иду.
Вообще мне нужна программа, которая будет считывать данные Excel таблицы а после выявлять корреляцию(от -1 до 1) этих данных

Comment: Так это можно и в одном массиве сделать, вы же можете `array[i, j]` и `array[i + 1, j]` сравнить?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не совсем пойму как это сделать(((
Я в программирование зеленый новичок еще, а курсовую как то делать надо:/

Comment: кажется в задаче решается то что уже реализовано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/Как-просто-работать-с-открыть-изменить-сохранить-excel-xlsx-csv-файлы/560134#560134

Comment: Вы же как-то написали этот код. В общем, не выдумывайте массивы. Если хотите помощи с решением задания, дополните вопрос деталями, чтобы было однозначно понятно, что именно требуется, какой ожидается результат и покажите вашу попытку решить задачу, даже если она неудачная. Кстати, странно, что вам дают такую сложную курсовую, когда вы сравнить 2 элемента массива затрудняетесь. Быть может стоит у преподавателя попросить задание попроще?