# Постоянное чтение в программу C# динамически изменяющихся данных из Excel (csv)

Tags: c#, excel

Тут представлен НЕ рабочий пример цикла для считывания каждые 6000 мс

List List = new List();

```
        int otv = 1;
        while (otv != 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Input.csv"))
            {
                
                //цикл пока не достигли конца файла
                while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
                {
                    //помещаем строку из файла в строковый массив по разделителю, принятому в csv
                    string str = sr.ReadLine();
                    //помещаем в элемент списка новую структуру типа Znachenia 
                    List.Add(new Znachenia() { Znachenie = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(str)) });
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
        }
    
            foreach (Znachenia Dannie in List)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(Dannie)) ;
        }

    }
    public struct Znachenia
    {
        public double Znachenie;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Convert.ToString(Znachenie);
        }

    }
```

Comment: А что тут не работает? В чём именно проблема?

Comment: Данные в цсв файле каждую секунду изменяются, сторонней программой. То есть по задумке программы  я считываю значения,  сортирую и заношу в sql таблицу.  Данные изменяются, начинается новая итерация. Программа должна работать с файлом 24/7

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Мы угадать должны? Попробую угадаю - у вас виснет программа. Если да - ставьте таймер и читайте по таймеру, а не слипом. А если уже хотите слип - создайте отдельный поток, и в нём делайте sleep. Однопоточная программа (вероятнее всего у вас такая, это по умолчанию) не может и работать и спать одновременно. Или спим или работаем. Но это не точно)))

Comment: Можете привести пример бесконечного цикла по таймеру, пожалуйста ?

Comment: Так таймер это и есть бесконечный цикл. Его таймер-хандрер будет выполняться раз в 6 сек бесконечно без всяких слипов. Открываем гугл. Пишем "msdn timer", открываем самую первую ссылку https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer даже с примерами и даже есть по-русски

Comment: Плюс для 24/7 надо вручную отключть "засыпание" компа, или погуглить как на c# делается препятствование ухода компа в сон.

Comment: А зачем тут таймер? Если вам надо выполнять действия, если файл был изменен, то и подпишитесь на событие изменения файла, делая по его вызову нужные действия.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это сложнее. Но тоже вариант. Для новичков наверно таймер попроще

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробовать таймер.

Comment: @nick_n_a Если человек работает с базой данных (а судя по `сортирую и заношу в sql таблицу`, это используется), то это уже явно не новичок и он должен уметь разбираться в том, как устроены классы, ибо следить за изменением файла, это инициализировать класс с нужными настройками и запустить, все. Если же это сложно, то автору явно рано еще вообще лезть в базу и работу с файлами, стоит подучить базовые понятия языка.

Comment: А данные как меняются? Новые поверх старых или просто новые добавляются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. для проверки изменений файловой системы оптимально использовать FileSystemWatcher
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory
2. Для считывания цсв я советую воспользоваться библиотеку из вижуал бейсика или враппер на нее [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/Как-просто-работать-с-открыть-изменить-сохранить-excel-xlsx-csv-файлы/560134#560134](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-excel-xlsx-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B/560134#560134)
3. Что бы не считывать слишком часто - желательно делать это не чаще чем условных 3-4 секунды. Мало ли как там запись будет происходить. Если же наверняка контролированная и не слишком частая - то почему бы и не считывать вообще каждый раз как изменяется файловая система. Будь то раз на 2 секунды или раз на час.
4. Считывать данные лучше в бекграундном потоке. И когда они считались полностью(файл же может быть великоват), только тогда уже переносить их в необходимое место связанное с фронтендом.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь