# Чтение CSV файла с помощью CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csv-helper

Всем привет, я новичок. Хочу получить данные с файла CSV - поля Id и Name, но при запуске метода чтения, я получаю только 100 строк непонятного типа: "CsvHelper.CsvReaderd__87`1[Program+Product]". Как получить данные с CSV я не знаю, понять где ошибка я тоже не могу.

Хотя в документации написано, что имея одинаковые имена свойств и заголовков CSV, то писать дополнительные конфигурации не нужно. Однако получаю результат указанный выше. Имена CSV совпадают с классами. Ссылка на документацию: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/

```
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Product>();
            Console.WriteLine($"{records}");
        }
    }
```

CSV создается без проблем, имеются два столбца с Id и Name
с заполненными строками, всего строк 100:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам метод создания csv с полями Id и Name:

```
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(products);
    }
```

Вот весь код на всякий случай:

```
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Product(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
    public const string PathToDoc = "C:/Users/Saint/Desktop/TaskRetail/yml.xml";


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1sSR9kWifwjIP5qFWcyxGCxN0-MoEd_oo?alt=media&key=AIzaSyBsW_sj1GCItGBK0vl8hr9zu1I1vTI1Meo";
        string savePath = @"C:\Users\Saint\Desktop\TaskRetail\yml.xml";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(url, savePath);

        Research();
    }

    public static void Research()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(PathToDoc);
        var xmlDoc = document.SelectNodes("/yml_catalog/shop/offers/offer");
        var count = xmlDoc.Count;
        var products = new List<Product>();
        Console.WriteLine($"Offers count: {count}");
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var element = xmlDoc.Item(i);
            var id = int.Parse(element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value);
            var name = element.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
            var product = new Product(id, name);
            //Console.WriteLine($"Id: {id}, name: {name}");

            products.Add(product);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(products);
            }

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";" };
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))

    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Product>();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{record.Id} {record.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: возможно будет полезным: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/Как-просто-работать-с-открыть-изменить-сохранить-excel-xlsx-csv-файлы/560134?r=SearchResults&s=2|56.2669#560134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вывсети на экран сразу коллекцию записей так:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{records}");
```

Коллекцию записей просто так выводить нельзя. Точнее можно, но вызовется базовая реализация `ToString()`, которая выводит просто название типа и прочее. Чтобы вывести каждую запись поочереди с новой строки, вы должны перебрать коллекцию, например через цикл `foreach`:

```
foreach (var record in records)
    Console.WriteLine(record);
```

Однако ваш класс `Product` также не переопределяет метод `ToString()`, по-этому вы снова увидете базовую реализацию. Как перезагрузить `ToString()` для своего типа рассказанно [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#overriding-the-objecttostring-method).

Также, вместо того, чтобы перезагружать `ToString()`, можете просто выводить отдельные поля:

```
foreach (var record in records)
    Console.WriteLine($"{record.Id} {record.Name}");
```

**UPD:**

Ошибка `Header with name 'id'[0] was not found.Header with name 'name'[0] was not found` возникает из-за того, как `CsvHelper` записывает и считывает данные.

По-умолчанию, при записи он записывает в файл все поля класса (`Id` и `Name`), а при считывании исчет конструктор, который принимает аргументы с названиями из заглавного столбца (те же `Id` и `Name`). Такого конструктора нет, так как в конструкторе все имена с маленькой буквы, вот он и кидает ошибку. Чтобы решить эту проблему у меня есть 2 варианта.

Первый вариант: подготовить заголовки, приведя их к нижнему регистру. Для этого нужен такой конфиг:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    PrepareHeaderForMatch = (args) => args.Header.ToLower()
};
```

Второй вариант разрешить присваивать поля без конструктора. Для этого в классе `Person` нужно сделать публичный пустой конструктор и в `csvReader` передать такой конфиг:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    ShouldUseConstructorParameters = type => false
};
```

Comment: Пытаюсь использовать ваш код без перегрузки методов, не получает получить записи Id и name. Потому что переменная records получает: "CsvHelper.CsvReaderd__87`1[Program+Product]" и следовательно цикл foreach не находит Id и name в heade'r. Я не думаю, что это связано с переопределением. Я скорее всего что-то не до конца понимаю, потому что у меня пока что проблемы с написанием самостоятельного кода, который выходит за рамки туториалов

Comment: @OttoRahn пожалуйста, добавьте новый код в вопрос, потому что я ничего не понял из комментария

Comment: переменная records получает: "CsvHelper.CsvReaderd__87`1[Program+Product]" и следовательно цикл foreach не находит Id и name. На переменной reader в цикле foreach возникает ошибка: "CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: 'Header with name 'id'[0] was not found.Header with name 'name'[0] was not found"

Comment: Внес изменения в код и добавил конфиг, все равно возникает ошибка:  "CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: 'Header with name 'id'[0] was not found.Header with name 'name'[0] was not found"

Comment: @OttoRahn обновил ответ