# Как отобразить таблицу Excel в WinForm?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, datagridview

Как перебрать таблицу excel, чтобы можно было показать ее например в `ListView` или `DataGridView`?

Comment: Office Interop например. Есть также NuGet пакеты для чтения xlsx

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать сторонние библиотеки, поддерживающие формат xlsx.
Использовать Interop не рекомендую (в основе его лежит медленный COM и требуется наличие MS Office).

Использовал библиотеку EPPlus. Она бесплатна для некоммерческого использования.
Позволяет [читать ячейки](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus.Sample.NetCore/blob/master/02-ReadWorkbook/ReadWorkbookSample.cs), а можно [загрузить диапазон ячеек в DataTable](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus.Sample.NetCore/blob/master/25-ImportAndExportDataTable/DataTableSample.cs).

Добавьте nuget пакет EPPlus в ваше приложение, а далее используйте вышеуказанные примеры кода для чтения Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Считай все ячейки из документа и поставь как контент датагридвью.

Если ты умеешь пользоваться 2хмерным масивом и датагридвьюхой - у тебя проблем не возникнет в принципе, если воспользуешся вот этим ответом:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134)