# Как DLL Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll перенести вместе с приложением на другой ПК?

Tags: c#

Имеется проект в нем используется Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll в нем добавлена библиотека через ссылку и все работает, однако приложение используется на другом ПК где нет Офиса, а соответственно и библиотеки. Как можно указать путь и перемещать с приложением эту библиотеку. Вариант DllImport не совсем то что мне нужно, потому что добавлять все методы которые используются не вариант, и не уверен что после этого приложение будет работать так как мне нужно. Можно ли как то иначе подменять путь к DLL?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=excel

Answer (score 0):

При использовании Microsoft.Office.Interop - установка офиса является обязательной.

Интероп запускает приложение офиса и взаимодействует с непосредственно с ним. Нету офиса - нету с чем взаимодействовать.

Из этого можно прийти к выводу что существует 2 выхода из ситуации:

- Установить офис на машину где будет запускаться программа
- Использовать иной путь для редактирования офисных документов

Если интероп используется для редактирования ексель файлов - советую ознакомиться с этим вопросом:  [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/560133/186752)