# Можно ли копировать данные из части Excel листа в DataGridView Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview

Есть Excel документ, хочу выделить часть столбцов и часть ячеек листа и скопировать в DGW, который имеет 4 столбца. Этого не дает сделать, возможно ли как-то настроить DGW, чтобы можно было вставить через буфер обмена и чтобы автоматом добавилось нужное количество строк?

Comment: посмотрите этот пример и адаптируйте под себя - https://coderoad.ru/6424514/DataGridView-%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: загружаешь как 2хмерный массив, обрезаешь лишние данные, применяешь данные в датагрид https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134