# Распознание похожих фраз C#

Tags: c#, строки

Разрабатывается система для хранения продуктов и их атрибутов. От поставщиков может поступать товары с одинаковыми по смыслу атрибутами, но у нас уже имеется список атрибутов из базы и нам нужно определить похожие по смыслу атрибуты. Например такие атрибуты как:

```
Цвет товара, Цвет
```

Где `Цвет товара` имеет такой же смысл как и `Цвет`.
Или например:

```
Ножи какие-то туристические, Туристические ножи
```

Эти фразы должны быть распознаны как одинаковые по смыслу и примениться нужное мне значение из базы, чтобы атрибуты товара не дублировались в базе. Как можно проверить это на C#? Есть ли какие-то паттерны или алгоритмы? Может функции самого шарпа?

Comment: Самое простое - [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0). Плюс разбивка по словам и сравнение коллекций слов, пересечение множеств.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь разобраться в этом

Comment: Расстояние Левенштейна - это можно даже для каждого в отдельности взятого слова. Например вы с помощью него сможете поймать общее между "Нож туристический" и "Ножи туристические". Здесь где-то даже были примеры реализации.

Comment: @aepot Ну, с Левенштейном надо аккуратнее. Он может дать весьма неожиданные результаты и показать похожесть где её вообще не ожидаешь. Матчинг товаров - задача не такая простая. На первое приближение может и пойдёт, но боюсь в итоге к ручным правилам придётся прийти.

Comment: @CrazyElf вообще с программированием как бы не стоит терять бдительность при разработке. :)

Comment: @aepot Это да, но Левенштейн реально коварен, особенно на некоторых словах )  Надо конечно смотреть конкретные данные, но... Особенно, если какие-то цифры ещё будут в строках, то "Стол арт. 1234567" будет гораздо ближе к "Стул арт. 1234589", чем "Стол деревянный", например %)  А удалять цифры - тоже не вариант, где-то наоборот по цифрам близость будет правильная. )

Comment: Мне кажется тут можно надрессировать простенькую нейронку на том же ML.Net, даже проект созданный через конструктор студии на классификацию текста с этим справится, особенно, если у вас статичные атрибуты (судя по комментом под ответом ниже). Минусы тут, конечно, в том, что нужен хотяб минимальный дата сет, в котором вы укажете что "вес" может быть "вес товара", "вес продукта" и др. обозначения, ну и в процессе дополнять его, обучая нейронку. Ну и еще минус - может кушать прилично так ресурсов при угадывании. Но результат, со статичными атрибутами, весьма думаю хороший будет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ваш ответ, попробую изучить ML .NET

Comment: @АлександрОкостень Ну, это лишь комментарий, а не ответ) Если не разберетесь, пишите, простенький пример думаю показать смогу (хоть и сам не особо разбираюсь в нейронках).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Что-то я не уверен, что для матчинга нейронка сама по себе будет хороша. Там больше надо думать, как данные для неё готовить.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, но с этими данными у человека хотя бы возможность без проблем исправить неверный вывод, чем в том же расстоянии с теми же столами и стульями, ведь достаточно скормить нейронке новые данные, где будет содержаться новое слово и хотя бы минимальный набор соответствий, и она уже с большой вероятностью будет выдавать правильные догадки. Опять же, да, это не 100% вариант, зависит от многих факторов, но если грамотно подойти, то он будет лучше расстояния. Я позже попробую все же сделать простенький пример, если выйдет что годное, оформлю ответом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ буду благодарен

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас предугадываемые данные статичны, то задачу можно отдать нейронным сетям. Но в этом подходе есть один недостаток, а именно **данные**, ведь чем их больше, чем они точнее, тем лучше работает нейронная сеть.

Давайте покажу самый простейший вариант с использованием ML.Net, нам даже код не придется писать.

1. Данные. Создадим простой текстовый файл, в котором будем построчно писать то что мы получаем и то, чем оно является, ну и разделим это неким символом:

   ```
    Окраска|Цвет
    Расцветка|Цвет
    Color|Цвет
    Весовой показатель|Вес
    Масса|Вес
    Нож туристический с фиксированным клинком|Туристические ножи
    Туристический нож Киридаши|Туристические ножи
    Скелетный нож туриста|Туристические ножи
    Стол арт. 26584|Стол
    Стол артикул 68245|Стол
    Стол красный|Стол
    Стол на металлических ножках|Стол
    Стул арт. 83576|Стул
    Стул артикул 12745|Стул
    Стул с подлокотниками|Стул
    Стул игровой|Стул
   ```

Как видите, простая табличка с неким наброском тестовых даных.

2. Создание модели.

   1. Жмем в студии правой кнопкой по проекту, добавить, там будет "ML.Net" или как вон в современных "Модель машинного обучения"
      [image: Add ml]
   2. Должен открыть окно с выбором сценария, нас интересует "Классификация данных".
   3. Далее спросит на какой машине производить вычисления (я выберу свою).
   4. На следующем этапе попросит данные для анализа, выбираем там наш заготовленный текстовый файл, смотрим чтоб в табличке было все как надо, а также выбираем "Column to predict" - та колонка, которую нейронка должна предугадать.
      [image: Data Select]
   5. На следующем шаге уже можно запустить процесс обучения. Этот механизм будет циклично прогонять одни и те же данные, но с разными алгоритмами, выбирая тот, который даст более точный результат. Время - чем больше, тем лучше, но и зависит от [размера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/machine-learning/automate-training-with-model-builder#how-long-should-i-train-for) файла с данными. Я лично запущу на 30 сек, ибо файлик всего и пары строк. Обратите внимание на значение "наилучшая точность" - чем чище у вас данные, чем их больше, точнее, тем лучше этот показатель, а значит и лучше будет результат. Мои данные выдали всего `0.49` попугаев, но для теста думаю хватит.
   6. На следующем этапе вы уже можете попробовать свою модель, написав там входные значения.
   7. Ну и на последнем этапе, он предложит создать консольный проект, куда поместит вашу натренированную модель и покажет, как с ней обращаться.
3. Код. Давайте теперь опробуем нашу модель. В созданном консольном проекте мы можем менять все, что захотим, как захотим, но сейчас нас интересует лишь посмотреть на полученный результат. Давайте напишем такой простой код, запустим, ну и посмотрим что скажет:

   ```
    using MLModel1_ConsoleApp1;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Текст: ");
        MLModel1.ModelInput sampleData = new()
        {
            Col0 = Console.ReadLine()
        };

        var result = MLModel1.Predict(sampleData);
        Console.Write($"Результат: {result.PredictedLabel}\n\n");
    }
   ```

Результат выполнения:

> Текст: Нож, сталь d2, с рукоятью серого цвета
> Результат: Туристические ножи
>
> Текст: Цуиет изделия
> Результат: Цвет
>
> Текст: Вес изделия
> Результат: Цвет
>
> Текст: Вес
> Результат: Цвет
>
> Текст: Стол коричневого цвета со спинкой
> Результат: Стол
>
> Текст: Стул на колесика
> Результат: Стул
>
> Текст: Игровой стол с регулировкой уровня
> Результат: Стол
>
> Текст: Нож
> Результат: Туристические ножи

Как видите, даже ничтожные `0.49` "попугаев" выдали весьма такой относительно хороший результат. Стул от стола разделяет, может догадываться аж по целым предложениям к чему относится оно, проглатывает ошибки, опечатки. Заметьте кстати, что "Вес" он принимает за "Цвет" - это наглядно показывает то, что модели нахватает данных, ибо для веса в моем текстовом документе всего 2 значения. Так что, кол-во данных, их качество и прочие показатели, это очень важно для нейронки! Но даже в таком виде, как по мне, это уже лучше, чем расстояние левенштейна, хотя как знать...

Comment: Спасибо тебе!!!

Comment: Подробно и доходчиво для изучающих. Даже не знала что на нете такое есть. Буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Я бы подошел к этому вопросу с полуавтоматическим и полуручным подходом.

А точнее:

1. вбил базы поставщиков и сравнил бы Левенштейном все товары
2. создал бы ексель таблицу с результатами где главной первой колонкой выступали бы имена с личной базы товаров
3. пройтись по таблице вручную человеком
4. Перепроверить по таблице вручную иным человеком

После этого создать анализатор который вычисляет новые товары в базах данных которых нет в таблице что бы они так же перепроверялись вручную во избежание ошибок при будущих пополнениях баз данных

Ссылку на [Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) продублирую из комментариев

Работу с Ексель или CSV можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-excel-xlsx-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B/560134#560134)

Comment: Хороший ответ, но тут речь идёт конкретно про названия атрибутов у товара
К примеру
Один поставщик прислал товары у которых есть атрибут "Вес"
И второй поставщик прислал товары, где есть атрибут "Вес товара"
Дак вот система должна распознать, что Вес и Вес товара это один и тот же атрибут и присвоить "Вес" для последующих атрибутов похожих на это

Comment: Если это касается только атрибутов, а не товаров - то тогда еще проще. Потому что атрибуты товара меняются реже. Но подход - тот же.

Comment: Да, это касается именно атрибутов

Comment: Может удалять окончание слов, вероятно костыль...  Ножи туристические => нож турист

Comment: @Yotic Такое точно не подойдёт :)