# Как построить график прогнозирования скачков продаж на основании таблицы в БД с помощью ML.NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-core, ml.net

Хочу реализовать график ,где ML.NET будет прогнозировать продажи ,скачки ,используя EF Core Wpf C# net 6.0 .

В таблице продаж есть IdProduct,Quantity,Data,SelerId,ClientId.Как используя мои данные таблицы продаж ,построить график прогноза с помощью ML.NET

Результат нужен примерно такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это варик с интернета но здесь данные берутся из csv файда а мне надо из моего контекста или ProductSaleList

```
public class Program
{
    // filename for data set
    private static string dataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "shampoo-sales.csv");

    /// <summary>
    /// The main program entry point.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The command line parameters.</param>
    static void Main()
    {
        // create the machine learning context
        var context = new MLContext();

        // load the data file
        Console.WriteLine("Loading data...");
        var dataView = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<SalesRecord>(path: dataPath, hasHeader: true, separatorChar: ',');

        // get an array of data points
        var sales = context.Data.CreateEnumerable<SalesRecord>(dataView, reuseRowObject: false).ToArray();

        // the rest of the code goes here...
    }
}
```

Используется для графика PLplot

Comment: ПКМ по проекту - ML.NET конструктор, там просто делаете шаг за шагом нужное вам, включая настройку подключения к базе данных. Я помню [показывал пример конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1383461/220553), думаю будет полезно. Как только вам конструктор сделает код, смотрите что там и как сгенерировано, и уже либо целиком переносите к себе в проект, либо настраивайте имеющийся код. P.S. Если не ошибаюсь, то предугадывание идет по одному, а не целыми массивами, хотя я в этом особо не разбирался. Это означает то, что вам надо заготовленные данные последовательно прогонять через ML.

Comment: Понял , спасибо