# Как сгруппировать спаршенный контент ИИшкой?

Tags: парсер, искусственный-интеллект

Хочу спарсить цитаты со страницы сайта. Там более 1700 цитат.
И сгруппировать их по смыслу. Ясное дело что ручками - не вариант.
Можно ли сделать это каким-нибудь ИИ инструментом и как? Спасибо!

Comment: Что значит "по смыслу"? Смысл у всех свой) Тут стоит привести пример того, что получаете, и того, что ожидаете на выходе. Также может подобная информация уже есть на сайте? Ну а так, нейронка - это данные, чем больше данных тем лучше, берите эти данные, присваивайте им категорию, ну а потом эти данные отдавайте нейронке для обучения, получите мб то, что хотите. На C# можно допустим сделать [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1383461/220553), простой конструктор, который за вас напишет код, а дальше его модифицируйте как надо. Но повторю - данные, чем больше и качественней, тем лучше.