# Как улучшить мой алгоритм написания словаря для определения тональности текста?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Я хочу создать свой словарь с оценкой негативности/позитивности слов. Т. е. будет файл в котором будут слова и их оценка (негативное, позитивное, нейтральное).

Вот такой алгоритм мне пришел в голову:

1. я нахожу источники текста и разделяю их на позитивные и негативные
2. Перед парсингом чищу текст от запятых предлогов и вводных слов и перевожу слова в начальную форму
3. делаю парсинг источника и самым частым словам в количестве 30% от текста присваиваю ярлык негативные(если сейчас идет парсинг негативного источника)
4. Аналогично с позитивными

Так вот мои вопросы:

1. Насколько этот алгоритм плох и как его улучшить?
2. как найти нейтральные слова?
3. что делать со словами которые и позитивные и негативные?
4. Как можно реализовать числовую оценку позитивности/негативности в диапазоне каком-то?

Comment: Для таких задач лучше делать свою нейронную сеть, и проще, и надежней (зависит от данных, которые вы дадите на тренировку). [Самый простейший пример для начинания (ML.NET)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1383461/220553), в конструкторе выберите нужный тип нейронки, дайте ей базовый набор данных, и она будет вам определять "тональность текста" сразу из коробки.

Comment: А если я хочу воспользоваться именно методом словарей не могли бы вы дать совет как улучшить тот алгоритм что я имею

Comment: Нет, ибо я не думаю, что вы сможете сделать адекватное определение типа любого текста вот такими простыми, базовыми алгоритмами. Ну вот условно, я напишу "Привет" - позитив? Скорей нейтрал, ок, допустим это у вас есть в вашем "словаре" и он понимает тональность этого слова. Хорошо, а если будет "прив"? Тут уже ваш алгоритм схлопнется если вы только не сделаете к примеру "Растояния Левенштейна" и его аналоги. Ок, а допустим человек написал "Приветик", что тогда? Это уже "позитивный" тон, как тогда поступите? Ваш алгоритм сейчас по сути "статичен", где малейшее изменение даже буквы - это крах.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ На коротких текстах никакая самая продвинутая нейросеть не даст хорошего результата )

Comment: @CrazyElf Как и любой базовый алгоритм. Ну а в нейронках все зависит от датасета, чем он лучше, тем больше она умеет. Вот к примеру то, о чем я первым комментарием написал, датасет сгенерирован др. нейронкой из самых базовых фраз, там их 50 штук, то есть это самый паршивый датасет, но и он дает уже [относительно хороший результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAzjw.png), да не без [огрехов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPhqt.png), но дополняем датасет и вот то, [что нужно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmfoN.png). Попробуйте как говорится сделать тоже самое простыми алгоритмами, сомневаюсь что получится

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну, вообще чтобы слово "прекрасно" (нормализованное "прекрасна") не попало в сугубо позитивные - это очень странный датасет ))

Comment: @CrazyElf Как я и сказал выше "самый паршивый датасет", слепил за 5 минут на коленке. Но с задачей ведь справляется? Не идеально, да, но справляется, даже определяет то, чего нет в датасете. Ну а теперь тоже самое пробуем сделать базовыми алгоритмами, как вон автор предлагает, словарь, неужели он справиться с поставленной задачей? Как я и сказал выше, эти все "статичные" алгоритмы от малейшей перестановки буквы схлопнуться. Так что, лучшим вариантом тут всеж будет нейронка, которая с хорошим датасетом будет хорошо определять тональность почти любый предложений.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ То, что нейросети оптимальны для обработки текстов и картинок я вообще спорить не буду )

Answer (score 2):

1. Насколько этот алгоритм плох и как его улучшить?

   - В данном алгоритме не учитываются "веса" слов. Одни слова могут сильно влиять на тональность, другие не очень.
   - Не учитываются сочетания слов (2-3 слова, идущие подряд), а это тоже может дать прирост качества.
   - Не используются частоты, с которыми слова встречаются во всём корпусе и в конкретных источниках. Посмотрите к примеру на преобразование `TF/IDF`.
2. как найти нейтральные слова?
3. что делать со словами которые и позитивные и негативные?
   Это на самом деле один вопрос, а не два. Слова, которые не сильно влияют на тональность (или бывают обоих тональностей) должны иметь малый вес при определении тональности.
4. Как можно реализовать числовую оценку позитивности/негативности в диапазоне каком-то?
   Проще всего всё-таки использовать какой-то алгоритм машинного обучения для этого, он сам подберёт веса слов и сделает преобразование количества слов в итоговую оценку 0 или 1, где скажем 0 - это негатив, а 1 - это позитив. Почитайте, например, про логистическую регрессию. И обычно алгоритмы машинного обучения могут выдать не только результат в виде 0 и 1, но и степень уверенности в этом результате. Проще всего посмотреть формулы из логистической регрессии, как там результат предсказания преобразуется в диапазон [0-1].