# Считать данные, порядок которых указан в первой строке файла

Tags: c#, файлы

У меня есть файл вида:

```
Id;LastName;FirstName;BirthDate
1;Иванов;Иван;01.01.1990
2;Иванова;Мария;01.05.1998
3;Иванов;Петр;01.01.1980
```

Нужно считать данные, учитывая, что порядок их может меняться, например стать:

```
BirthDate;LastName;FirstName;Id
01.01.1990;Иванов;Иван;1
01.05.1998;Иванова;Мария;2
01.01.1980;Иванов;Петр;3
```

Что-то кроме как `switch` с множеством `case` ничего не приходит в голову, подскажите, пожалуйста. При чем дальше идет пустая строка и идут данные о их родстве. Возможно это важно, я думаю считывать просто `while (str != string.Empty)`.

Вот пример полного файла на всякий случай:

```
Id;LastName;FirstName;BirthDate
1;Иванов;Иван;01.01.1990
2;Иванова;Мария;01.05.1998
3;Иванов;Петр;01.01.1980
4;Иванова;Ольга;01.01.1971
5;Петрова;Маргарита;01.01.1972
6;Иванов;Олег;02.03.1995

3<->4=spouse
3<->1=parent
4<->1=parent
5<->3=sibling
6<->4=sibling
```

Сам файл лежит в формате `.txt`, поэтому считываю просто:
`string[] readedFile = File.ReadAllLines(DataWriter.PathOfFile);`

Хочу считать в `List<Human>`.
Сам класс:

```
public class Human
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; private set; }
    }
```

Вообще, мне нужно считать данные и сохранить в объекты, затем обращаясь например у людей с Id 1 и 2 должен вернуться тип "sibling", хотя этого не было указано в файле явно. Но я не понимаю пока как правильно здесь реализовать объектную модель.

Comment: Вы пробовали сами реализовать чтение файла? Если да, стоит приложить код к вопросу. Также, приложите структуру/класс, в который нужно считать данные

Comment: @AndreiKhotko дополнил

Comment: Также появилась идея считать первую строку, сгенерировать все её перестановки и затем сравнивать их

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю следующий подход:

1. Создать `enum` на основе строковых значений
2. Создать класс с всеми необходимыми полями
3. Спарсить первую строку, чтобы понять последовательность значений относительно типа столбца (enum)
4. Спарсить все остальные на основе конструкции `switch case` , ориентируясь на последовательность значений из п.3

в рамках псевдокода:

```
var tmp = someClass();

switch firstRowEnums[i] {
 case .id: 
    tmp.id = cell[i][j];
 case .firstName:
    tmp.firstName = cell[i][j];
 case .lastName:
    tmp.lastName = cell[i][j];
 case .birth:
    tmp.birth = cell[i][j];
}

dataList.add(tmp);
```

Еще может быть полезным https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560134/186752

Comment: А как мы поймем  последовательность значений относительно типа столбца (enum)? И примерно, что в `switch case` подразумеваете

Comment: Просто у меня голове `swtich` с 16 кейсами, которые просто содержат все перестановки

Comment: обновил ответ. Т.к. синтаксиса шарпа не помню - писал в рамках псевдокода. i = столбец. j = строка

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую реализовать

Comment: А вы ведь в пункте "2" про класс `Human` из моего вопроса? Или какой-то другой класс

Comment: Блин и не пойму все-таки пункт "3". "чтобы понять последовательность значений относительно типа столбца (enum)" как это все-таки понять. Я её спарсил, но как сопоставить не пойму

Comment: да, про клас хьюман

Comment: да вот свитч кейс который я написал в ответе и сопоставляет. Пройдись циклом этим свитч кейсом по всем ячейкам строки и твой тмп и будет готовым спаршенным обьектом Хьюмана