# C# прочитать csv с 2 строками в заголовке

Tags: c#, .net, csv-helper

Может кто подскажет как это сделать.

Есть такой csv

```csv
;;temperature ID1;water ID1
;;C;moh
2022.05.22;07:00;8,5;499,24
2022.05.22;08:00;10,3;499,24
```

Как видно из приведенного куска файла, имеется две строки заголовка в начале, да еще и с пустыми значениями.

На выходе я хочу иметь вот такой набор значений

```cs
public class Records
{
    public DateOnly Dates { get; set; }
    public string Times { get; set; }
    public float Moh { get; set; }
    public float Temperature { get; set; }

}
```

Попробовал решить через ручную обработку и она естественно работает. Меня беспокоит только, что приходится разделять по `\r\n`, поскольку нет гарантии существования этого разделителя в файлах. Вот это

```cs
List<Records> records = new List<Records>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader("csvs\\test.csv"))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split("\r\n");

        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            var values_sep = item.Split(";");
            try
            {
                var record = new Records{
                    Dates = DateOnly.Parse(values_sep[0]),
                    Times = values_sep[1],
                    Moh = float.Parse(values_sep[2]),
                    Temperature = float.Parse(values_sep[3])
                };
                records.Add(record);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Далее я попробовал [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), но настройка конфигурации сбивает с толку и получилось отделить полезную нагрузку от заголовков только через `switch/case`. Поставил заглушки в виде `System.Console.WriteLine`, чтоб не загромождать код.

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
    Delimiter=";"
};
using (var reader = new StreamReader("csvs\\test.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        switch (csv.GetField(0))
        {
            case "":
                System.Console.WriteLine("Headers Here");
                break;
            default:
                System.Console.WriteLine("Record here");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос, есть ли возможность читать такого плана csv файлы без костылей и хардкода? Или мои решения вполне приемлимы в области C#?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Comment: @Andrew Побывал я у вас, почитал и на github заглянул. У вас отличное решение. Но можете ли вы ответить, как парсить файл с наличием двух строк заголовков? Помимо того, что хардкодить  `Skip()` при проверке существования заголовков. Я оценил ваш ответ, но это не то, что я ищу

Comment: Если чесно вообще не понимаю в проблема обработки двух строк заголовков. Проверяешь первые 2 строки на возможные заголовки и обрабатываешь необходимым способом все остальные строки.

Comment: Хотя имхо - 2 строки заголовков это что-то странное. Но снова таки - я не вижу ни наименьшей проблемы в обработке.

Comment: Делаешь энам с возможными заголовками. Проверяешь на вхождение этих слов в любой из ячеек первых двух строк. Если есть совпадение - то в этой колонке данных находятся данные относящиеся к этому заголовку. Записываешь это дело в дикшинари заголовок и колонка.  После этого проходишся циклом по всем строкам и вытягиваешь необходимые данные в твой рекорд соотнося с дикшинари.

Comment: Мой ответ рулит просто потому, что там поддерживается полная спецификация цсв - там есть и поддержка многострочных ячеек и поддержка ячеек в которых есть делимитер-символ. Чего вобщем-то нету в ответе Александра Петрова. А кто его знает какие данные ты там собираешся хранить на практике если не сейчас то в будущем

Comment: @Andrew не моя прихоть 2 заголовка. Работаю с тем, что получаю. Делиметер определен в документации, поэтому все что содержит другой разделитель, для меня не релевнтно. Не спорю об эффективности и что это рулит или нет, поскольку не силен в с#, но задача не есть дубликат вопроса, предложенного вами. Поскольку нет согласия в Датском королевсте, буду пилить свой велосипед. В любом случае, спасибо, за наводки и подсказки :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не понял, зачем вы разделяете строки по `\r\n`. Ведь метод `ReadLine` класса `StreamReader` уже выдаёт вам готовую строку без этих символов.

Если нужно пропустить две строки заголовка, то это проще всего сделать с помощью linq-метода `Skip`:

```
File.ReadLines("test.csv").Skip(2)
```

Если нет гарантии, что заголоки присутствуют в файле, то фильтруем с помощью `Where`:

```
File.ReadLines("test.csv").Where(x => x[0] != ';')
```

Итоговый код может выглядеть так:

```
var records = new List<Records>();

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("test.csv").Where(x => x[0] != ';'))
{
    var values = line.Split(";");

    var record = new Records
    {
        Dates = DateOnly.Parse(values[0]),
        Times = values[1],
        Moh = float.Parse(values[2]),
        Temperature = float.Parse(values[3])
    };
    records.Add(record);
}
```

Или весь на LINQ:

```
var records = File.ReadLines("test.csv")
    .Skip(2) // или Where
    .Select(line =>
    {
        var values = line.Split(";");

        return new Records
        {
            Dates = DateOnly.Parse(values[0]),
            Times = values[1],
            Moh = float.Parse(values[2]),
            Temperature = float.Parse(values[3])
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: отвечая на вопрос зачем разделять по `\r\n`, все очень просто - нет опыта ни в C#, ни в его модулях или как правильно это называется. Смотрю, LINQ хорош

Comment: А зачем эти костыли, если есть `CsvHelper`? Даже автор его использует.

Comment: @aepot - а CsvHelper способен сам определить наличие или отсутствие двух строк заголовка?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, он избавляет от всяких `Split(';')`

Answer (score 1):

```
Csv csv = new Csv(); //создаем инстанс читалки

csv.FileOpen("c:\\file1.csv"); //открываем файл
```

дальше парсим лист строк в обьект Records (кстате лучше рекорд а не рекордС )

по мере необходимости сравниваем заголовок в первой строке, т.е. в

```
csv.Rows[0]
```

с ячейками внутри и тогда парсим.

Ничего особо сложного

https://github.com/ukushu/DataExporter